# Strict partitions of a positive integer

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, integer-partitions

OEIS [A000009](https://oeis.org/A000009) counts the number of *strict partitions* of the integers. A *strict partition* of a nonnegative integer `n` is a set of positive integers (so no repetition is allowed, and order does not matter) that sum to `n`.

For example, 5 has three strict partitions: `5`, `4,1`, and `3,2`.

10 has ten partitions:

```
10
9,1
8,2
7,3
6,4
7,2,1
6,3,1
5,4,1
5,3,2
4,3,2,1
```

### Challenge

Given a nonnegative integer `n`<1000, output the number of strict partitions it has.

#### Test cases:

```
0 -> 1

42 -> 1426
```

Here is a list of the strict partition numbers from 0 to 55, from OEIS:

```
[1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,12,15,18,22,27,32,38,46,54,64,76,89,104,122,142,165,192,222,256,296,340,390,448,512,585,668,760,864,982,1113,1260,1426,1610,1816,2048,2304,2590,2910,3264,3658,4097,4582,5120,5718,6378]
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution in bytes wins.

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 7 bytes

```
l{I#./Q
```

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=l%7BI%23.%2FQ&input=5&debug=0) [Test suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=l%7BI%23.%2FQ&input=5&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=5%0A10%0A0%0A42&debug=0)

- Take the input (`Q`).
- Find its partitions (`./`).
- Filter it (`#`) on uniquify (`{`) not changing (`I`) the partition. This removes partitions with duplicates.
- Find the result's length (`l`).

Answer (score 4):

### Python 2, 49 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k=1:n/k and f(n-k,k+1)+f(n,k+1)or n==0
```

The recursion branches at every potential summand `k` from `1` to `n` to decide whether it should be included. Each included summand is subtracted from the desired sum `n`, and at the end, if `n=0` remains, that path is counted.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 11 bytes

```
PartitionsQ
```

---

**Test case**

```
PartitionsQ@Range[10]
(* {1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,8,10} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 39 bytes

```haskell
f n=sum[1|x<-mapM(:[0])[1..n],sum x==n]
```

The function `(:[0])` converts a number `k` to the list `[k,0]`. So,

```haskell
mapM(:[0])[1..n]
```

computes the Cartesian product of `[1,0],[2,0],...,[n,0]`, which gives all subsets of `[1..n]` with 0's standing for omitted elements. The strict partitions of `n` correspond to such lists with sum `n`. Such elements are counted by a list comprehension, which is shorter than `length.filter`.

Comment: Brilliant! I was looking for a replacement for `subsequences` (+ `import`) in my answer myself, but didn't succeed so far.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 68 bytes

```
p=lambda n,d=0:sum(p(n-k,n-2*k+1)for k in range(1,n-d+1))if n else 1
```

Just call the anonymous function passing the nonnegative integer `n` as argument... and wait the end of the universe.

Comment: make it `n>0`, you save a byte and go faster (i believe you recurse on negative numbers) :P

Comment: Also, Memoizing this kind of speeds it up

Comment: Cant you change your if statement to: `return sum(...)if n else 1`

Comment: @randomra Of course, of course...

Answer (score 2):

### ES6, 64 bytes

```
f=(n,k=0)=>[...Array(n)].reduce((t,_,i)=>n-i>i&i>k?t+f(n-i,i):t,1)
```

Works by recursive trial subtraction. `k` is the number that was last subtracted, and the next number to be subtracted must be larger (but not so large that an even larger number cannot be subtracted). 1 is added because you can always subtract `n` itself. (Also since this is recursive I have to take care that all of my variables are local.)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
LæOQO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f5/Ay/0D///8NDQA)

Note: this is extremely slow and will timeout for inputs greater than about 20.

Explanation:

```
L         # range 1..input
 æ        # list of subsets
  O       # sum each subset
   Q      # equal? (1 for each sum that equals the input, 0 otherwise)
    O     # sum the booleans
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 58 bytes

```
import Data.List
h x=sum[1|i<-subsequences[1..x],sum i==x]
```

Usage example: `map h [0..10]` -> `[1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,8,10]`.

It's a simple brute-force approach. Check the sums of all subsequences of `1..x`. This works for `x == 0`, too, because all subsequences of `[1..0]` are `[[]]` and the sum of `[]` is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 43 bytes

```haskell
0%0=1
_%0=0
n%k=n%(k-1)+(n-k)%(k-1)
f n=n%n
```

The binary function `n%k` counts the number of strict partitions of `n` into parts with a maximum part `k`, so the desired function is `f n=n%n`. Each value `k` can be included, which decreases `n` by `k`, or excluded, and either way the new maximum `k` is one lower, giving the recursion `n%k=n%(k-1)+(n-k)%(k-1)`.

Comment: `n%k|q<-k-1=n%q+(n-k)%q` shaves a byte off of line 3.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `l`, 24 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 3 bytes

```
Ṅ'Þu
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJsPSIsIiIsIuG5hCfDnnUiLCIiLCI1Il0=)

Vyxal forever

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, 53 bytes

```
n->endof(collect(filter(p->p==∪(p),partitions(n))))
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts an integer and returns an integer. To call it, assign it to a variable.

We get the integer partitions using `partitions`, `filter` to only those with distinct summands, `collect` into an array, and find the last index (i.e. the length) using `endof`.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÅœʒDÙQ}g
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cOvRyacmuRyeGVib/v@/iREA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn3l/8OtRyefmuRyeGZgbfp/nf8GXKZchgZcJkYA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Åœ          # Get all integer partitions of the (implicit) input
            #  i.e. 5 → [[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,2],[1,1,3],[1,2,2],[1,4],[2,3],[5]]
  ʒ   }     # Filter by:
   D        #  Duplicate the current partition
    Ù       #  Uniquify (removing any duplicated values from) this copied partition
            #   i.e. [1,1,1,1,1] → [1]
            #   i.e. [1,4] → [1,4]
     Q      #  Check if it's still the same
            #   i.e. [1,1,1,1,1] and [1] → 0 (falsey)
            #   i.e. [1,4] and [1,4] → 1 (truthy)
       g    # Then take the length of the filtered list (and implicitly output it)
            #  i.e. [[1,4],[2,5],[5]] → 3
```