# Tut-tut-tut-tut-tut

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem

The string `tut-tutut-tut-tuttut-tut` can be constructed with overlapping or concatenated instances of the word `tut-tut`:

```
tut-tutut-tut-tuttut-tut
tut-tut
      tut-tut
          tut-tut
                 tut-tut
```

The string `tut-tututut-tutut-tut` cannot:

```
tut-tututut-tutut-tut
tut-tut^
       |tut-tut
       |      tut-tut
       |
this u is unaccounted for
```

Given a string, determine whether it's constructed of overlapping or concatenated instances of the word `tut-tut`. Where two or more `tut-tut` strings overlap they must share the same letters in the same positions.

#### Rules

- Standard I/O rules apply. You can use any two *distinct, consistent* values to distinguish the true and false cases.
- You may assume the input strings are nonempty and only contain lowercase ASCII letters and `-`.
- This is code golf, shortest code in bytes wins.

#### Test Cases

True:

```
tut-tut
tut-tut-tut
tut-tutut-tut
tut-tuttut-tut
tut-tut-tut-tut-tut
tut-tutut-tut-tutut-tut
tut-tutut-tut-tuttut-tut
tut-tut-tutut-tuttut-tut
tut-tuttut-tutut-tut-tutut-tut
```

False:

```
x
tut
tut-
-tut
t-tut
tu-tut
tut-tutx
tut-tutt
xtut-tut
ttut-tut
tutut-tut
tut-tu-tut
tut-tuttut
tuttut-tut
tut-tut-tutt
tut-tutt-tut
tut-tuttut-tu
tut-tututut-tut
tut-tuttuttut-tut
tut-tututut-tutut-tut
```

Comment: Did you mean to have a double `t` in the first example?

Comment: @xnor The intention is that the strings can be overlapped or concatenated, but I agree that's not very clear, I'll edit to clarify

Comment: suggest `tut-tut-tutt` as a test case

Comment: Wait this needs *way* more test cases, `tut-tutt-tut` for falsy :P

Comment: this is a great challenge though :-) it seems to have a surprising number of approaches

Comment: Is truthy/falsey output ok? I think at least some regex sols are producing that.

Comment: Suggested: `tutut-tut` – as the current test cases all pass [tsh's regex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251772/tut-tut-tut-tut-tut/251777#comment560691_251777)

Comment: @xnor I think since I've specified distinct and consistent answers should comply with that

Comment: @Sisyphus Well you just reminded me that today is my tut(orial) submission deadline. Thanks. +1

Answer (score 22):

## Regex (POSIX ERE / RE2 or better), <s>23</s> <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
^\b((t?\But)?-tut)+$
```

Based on regexes by thejonymyster and Bubbler.

[Try it on regex101!](https://regex101.com/r/o2oBkT/7) - RE2
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBdT4MwFH32/oqTQgaLIXGvMLLEhyU@65ubhkkjS5qhhUWi9bdj6WBlo/IAveeejx52WVW0kmc5IpkjCCCXy@C1f4L2ZbMLw3q1uT/W81VU6/et3w5r@ir2guNh/Ziit4BQ6hnRAcwXDNskL@lGz9/wK2yV4m9FmVTpIjHYidMJmP8j4rt48cuQgnkGDTuy4Sj@LvkHov0n17NkmM1gll3OkzzyGGBQyoLrTFQaZfPEYtqI8vLAWw@dhki36RoN3/H5cnIQ3YKp1OIOE@fiP0PyYFoRNTTQ6STs5WOX5mxHzTlglHSReRVP7ttayvS6tu6kzOSHjFv9AQ) - GNU ERE (Bash + egrep)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDdToMwFL7vU3TBrOdMYTMxXoxUEhN9APXOaYKsm9UOmlIUZ3x2LFMGE7xpe9rvty/xW5wnRmrr51ouhdlk6av4qAxPxTu9EeurUgNs@cV0Uj0ungBstLgsLEa@devxUTWZbjGw2a01Ml0DBrmSiYDzE/8MMVxlBiSfhaC4EfFSyVQA4oinhVKh5Kf4SSiVK5CoHd0Chm5WdDym6n72MOLMY/WgC5tbAyrYxDZ5BoMRuzOFmFPK5uw6Vrk7sh23QWL4VXm0BhHigtZhm717PpwGgMOEPrW9HxAZfPhPkHh014iQkjRw8kP8pXdVyr0cKfcGHacDzz/2ZDhtC@nHbev2yvQ@pNvqGw) - ECMAScript
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBLb4JAEL7Pr5jIxmVTDXLohRWJje2xJ4@kG20wIdmiXSChIfSv06GWh0IvO6/vMbOXyOjH@uMLmZFY6vP7QSNzJJX@erfdbzcVnM7GZrG/kuuNpOiKEuMTdUR5MXGS4SxMZrJCptHHND@mGcHVYukuXBF9NkMMBv0VTQR6yJQEJCG0iTifdwhNCFckEbd4a2A3EP8bHWYcEfC9ySMPkXv85aBTSrmQFWldwUxLrJR6ft0pVb@FR9vOgvApz0SwzOh9YHVtYSMBQHXTa@Mwv60mgNOEMbXvT4hMDv4TBAt/7wUooIXDlfhHH6oUnRwUncHA6cbzzh6mt@0h43X7c0fHjD5keNUP) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X1qcquDr7@ftGmmt4Brm6KMQGF2cWKmgkWsVYKofq1CnoGKblpmXWZwBZAZG6yvY2ysohRSVplopKCgpKCoqKLkl5hQDeUqaOirxCmn5RQo5mXmpxdax1lxQjf/jYpI0NErsY5xKSzTtdUuApLbK//9AGsTmgtLIbFQeFoXYNWBqRYhjMQSrBC4DK7hgirggyqGakPVWwA3hqoAbi2Q@ik1olnJhdyNCCaYjEZ7E8AJGMCD7BQA) - Raku<sup>`:P5`</sup>
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBbT4MwFMff@ymOXSOtsguvq4TEOI2JcQZ9E20Y6YRYGCldssT42edhXnbDB8rpv//zO5c6r9cXUZ3XwCyEQIcUBlBb/aasrk2aae4NB2eRUnlqnMoWZV0YbROeCJnEw8bzwcNvjqJ6062hcrpyDVfq@vZuopTwIRCIpMMllaSoCtVox2mdWT2Ypdm7s3goU5SFoz7QfkCFJPOF5awIR5KZcI7Yhj8@Xd3eCyk@oJhzZp4bZ42uMBL94CUMaVJRgeZmOcMXlP2R3w@E3LgLobN80VokIDWQBFAHvmWcniJy9HISej0PS7Ay3GygTF2Wc2Z9tEhoId@bMWnjlLYWuxQn4UM8uVH3UzWJ42kc0Umrj4GOOSsj@mSXegx4o9epaTDE8eATG9jQKDNUfh7slgu5fk1mnLsouVw6EfUdnudsve5BiyME7632@9@N928dxu6E49St3gHpfPgPSHqwmZ2QFfm1k@/En/RdyuoPR1Z/BXYq7dU8KE@6u91ajtvdjns0zNFCdqf6Ag) - PCRE
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFNb9swDIbv/hWsMzRSuqrZtYYXrMB6Wodh2W3ZAMWWY6Wy7Ely6yHwb8@o2PlqPB8skSIf8iXX/IXfrtPnrSyq0jhYo81kySYRnHpqJ9Wgz4iVaPxLVS@VTCBR3Fp44lLDpndZxx0eL6VMocAHMndG6hVws7I/f1FwuSlfLXxuElE5WWJiAPAolYAs1uJ1dyUhS8pUMHwPafRQZ5kwIv0ueCoMLHdh506yz@zNjNKor2vfu@g193xCbLxECTz9IrUglF7FulaKyoxYJv7UXFkS3k0mk5DSzXloRyDEDQI2SHAHAgLukLDEuOfI3sTjhR7700Vt52u/ceeE0WDi/oZqi8oXsDTCacwTrjUqlbqqHcTgxfU@Mv9rnSiY1BTXox3IeBpBr28Xz3Juv4rGYXuwAexMXsVT2qeV@F7hWJzSxAPiD74eVuxmpbBYB9FI6KUjA4hiSuiVywn9OIXra1Asybn55MgUhzAejelujf574i7JsfkCWYYVnUUUct72kJGCZVKnhMIMwh@mFvcAIdxD@IiDRAN3315keVTbtoFf1Pb3YolLmS0eakdntw7/N@@2fgHbEXhgEKDP@/fn6f3cGggcTrhMPfoHIIMP/wMGI9hpD4Im2IcHXWKffkppDrigORQ4qXRW8035YLjbY8hlu0e5F2IuBnKq6h8) - Java
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVLLbtswELzzK7ZyEVOJ7EYN0INkxUAO/YAihxa2K8g09UBliiApyHHgX69KUn7IscoDxV3OzuysSDifZIS0o4KRst5QmK2rSqovgmZ0N805f0YkTwTEfLGCCH44L03zZ/1U/3p7@/maf2ty3P5erjFW8@VLrdz5ROn94XPrfsQ5HtzzKOYPfoguYoXWEjTZPqOCKeBC7zEVohKYVEwqsNr3WyplklH3XapNEBANgNkMjllztHnKNmUIgqpaMPDDg6XcJgXDLrwj0IsvtFpJGebuxF9FjyHUGvP0NVZQmcgUZPpgwZZT4wuW6QteqxC6nuyAgsBOSMtpsvCUk9tEkRyaPFEdSVoJwIZ2b/gtZUZVWTCKOy8F8zp2TbKP/FOnZhUp4L0L@s5MAY@XbOyGV7e2cPG4grs7OJ0/RePR2D3DrG0z1hT3@44lTQTJOwbPNuxpLy7MwXkVNQ0AHAjA@Z6UUgdOTzhtRKFoVzklsZ4Qdo8eprLYUxP5nvFaGVe27mD346/R8z20IzAyCOnnYp7M6ds/X0cDwOGC29JLfoBk8OJ/hGgEdiII7dAJjrrCY3mfZXemQ7uzQE/pSvODPBru9gK5bfdi98bMzUD6rv6StEwy2U5K@0Ji@0D@AQ) – Try It Online") - Boost
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBLbsMgEN3PKaa4krGaRLayo0KRuugJurNTya2JgkSxBURycnkXmjp2arphGOZ95tGd3bHV20F@da1xaM92ZQQY5GgIIcN79UGp21UvJ5ft1s6fT4@DH5QFWxf7Z7zwHA6tQYVSB/LGukZqBojygBeGnZHa0ezaK6GpyrDWDarS0zlPK50yVFyVedCLwPL9A0@TdFQSuuHkzZwEQyQBbMTGitp8HqlZoWcJZQWS19oXhiQYT0SVhYWLIcGgAODjhEhjnd/vuwgwTlhSp/eISHTwnyAk@BMLoIcRDlfiL32u0t/koL8ZzJzuPP/YQ3zbCbJcd4q7CLP4kHmqbw) - Python
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDPT4MwFL73r/goZpsxNMzjSENmpkcPZreBZIt1NqmElJKxi/86FhiDCV7afu99P96rLg7nSoPjTRxFmbFUnLBZb9dMi/1HAMn9AKcvqQQUPwqTE0B@Qjp1PStMHkCkDW8Z1A2185Yx5zRKaWAVaucz5j3GDauVOoqJ78ycQ8xmlu7HDp@7c9sDMi1TAwX@A40QdKsLsQIoVqAve5VbQDunC7eFSfL8ukmS6j06LBYmjJ4Kcx96xp4Pd1XlojYixOK61t3D9y2aIE4LxtK@PmEy2fjPkLhodiakJB2dtMKLfOhSXu1IeQ0YJN1k/okn09P2lPG4/bqjZUYfMtzqFw) - Ruby
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDPT4MwFL73r3iBJm1VjF4hyxZNvHnz5jTB7SGNtZDSBTLC345lusFGvfS9134/3teyqNFUOSrVU7N4NfiJzVsca6z5ivXv6w/O7XL9sLNiGVl3XtOerW6Cx@K7lAq3gUjofnGXZIXBdJNzqkBqoFKXDtvKjNO9aGsjLUZ5UdnOge8TmYEDRqneRrqwQ6vkF7LwiokpGNyr20NJjRBQfmCZ2@fUbnKsHEsIaNmL2WEMrANUFbr5KXU1Zp2AoEv8WlR1fQgDkRAXaYh1rNP@fPIA/YQ5dbz3iHgf/hMkIRzyEdKQI5z8Ev/oU5XmJEeak8HE6czzwp74tx0h83XHuLMwsw@ZpvoB) - .NET

```
^            # Anchor to start of string.
\b           # Assert there is a word boundary here. Given the context, this is
             # equivalent to asserting that the first character isn't "-".
(
    (
        t?   # Optionally match and consume "t".
        \B   # Assert that this is not a word boundary. Given the context, this
             # is equivalent to asserting that the string does not start here.
        ut   # Match and consume "ut".
    )?       # Optionally match the above.
    -tut     # Match and consume "-tut".
)+           # Iterate the above as many times as possible, minimum one.
$            # Assert we've reached the end of the string.
```

Alternative 20 bytes:

```
^(tut-(tu\Bt?)?)+\b$
```

[Try it on regex101!](https://regex101.com/r/o2oBkT/8) - RE2
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDdToMwFL7vU3TBrOdMYTMxXoxUEhN9APXOaYKsm9UOmlIUZ3x2LFMGE7xoe077/ZyvL/FbnCdGauvnWi6F2WTpq/ioDE/FO70R66tSA2z5xXRSPYItrO@2xaWNMMLjxdNRNZluMbDZrTUyXQMGuZKJgPMT/wwxXGUGJJ@FoLgR8VLJVADiiKeFUqHkp/hJKJUrkKgd3QKGrld0PKbqfvYw4sxjdaMLm1sDKtjENnkGgxG7M4WYU8rm7DpWuSvZjtsgMfyqPFqDCKmHdqs5u/VhNwAcJvSp7f2AyODDf4LEo7tEhJSkgZMf4i@9q1Lu5Ui5N@g4HXj@sSfD07aQ/rht3F6Y3od0U30D) - ECMAScript
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDJTsMwEIbvforBtYgN6ZJrTRQJURASoihwI2ClkUsinDRyXKkS4tnLpCzdwsH2eOafb5Y6r9cXUZ3XwCyEQIcUBlBb/aasrk2aae4NB2eRUnlqnMoWZV0YbROeCJnEw8bzwcMzR6d6062gcrpyDVfq@vZuopTwIRCIpMMllaSoCtVox2mdWT2Ypdm7s3gpU5SFoz7QfkCFJPOF5awIR5KZcI7Yhj8@Xd3eCyk@oJhzZp4bZ42u0BL94CUMaVJRgeJmOcMIuv2R3w@E3KgLobN80UokIDWQBNAPfMs4PUXk6OUk9HoelmBluNlAmbos58z6KJHQQr43Y9LGKW0tdilOwod4cqPup2oSx9M4opPWPwY65qyM6JNd6jHgj16npkETx4NPbGBDo8xQ@XmwWy7k@pW7pevjlVy6SETiPJmx9boHLY6QNobn9921938dwu6E49StvwPSGfgPSHqwmZ2QFfmVk@/En/RdyuoPR1Z/BXYq7dU8KE@6u91Kjtvdjns0zNFCdqf6Ag) - PCRE

This version doesn't work properly in GNU ERE; it [matches `tut-tuttut-tu`](https://tio.run/##dVBda4MwFH3e/RWHKLUyhPVVK4U9FPa8va3dsDPMQqhbtEy27Le7mGpjayb4cc89HznusqpoJc9yRDJHEEAul8FrfwXty7w@1pF@bO7rVbgKbzc7vx3W9FXsBcfD@jFFbwGh1DOiA5gvGLZJXtKNnr/hV9gqxd@KMqnSRWKwE6cTMP9HxHfx4pchBfMMOu/IhqP4u@QfiPafXM@SYTaDWXY5T/LIY4BBKQuuM1FplIWJxbQR5eWBtx46DVHXTN/De/x9OTmIbsFUanGHiXPxnyF5MK2IGhrodBL28rFLc7aj5hwwSrrIvIon92ktZXpcW3dSZvJDxq3@AA). This appears to be a bug in GNU ERE, and is still present in the latest version. Note that `^(a\Bb?){2}$` incorrectly matches `aba`:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3BCoJAFEXX@RWXSVIXQrZ0lKCF0Lp2ZTE2QwqD1kgEOX67jZPh293zzn2vYG05KME4QsXheVBJ4l2n8YaLz867Yht0m94d/th5l5UU2GeHFFMVUusTwhrElQQ55Y2zMPkDt0WutbiVDW3TiFr2c8YCcTsZr@OoJ0hBlpb6o2wdLe5KPBBWT2GyIlitYJfjn6N6iRgg0HqGGZOtoSSgMzOHHN7UYmAF@wI) - GNU ERE (bug) / [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kKbE4Y8HOotTEFAXdohQFdXWFIhsb9XgoUF9aWpKma7EmTiMxxinJXrPaqFYFInRzH0wNV3lGZk6qgqdbsK0C1ByFnJqaaAXdPAUllRwlhVjrlHwuTiC_SkGlWCG2piY1OSPfutjW0BosBlED0qCkUp1jZWBlWKukYKugpAwW1QApBqupSU0vSi1Q0M0sTAXyi5QU1NQUwJIge0KKSlOtFBSUFGpqEIJuiTnFQFElTWuEGNAgrpT8vFSILxYsTkxKhDAB) (bug)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBfa8MgFMXf@ymck0ZH@id7rJPAWDoKox1Z35ZOTDBNmElF7VPpZ89uuofBHrxcj4ef9x7b2OEptY1FxCGB8AKjObJOH6XT1qhK02gxf0ilbJQJsjp1tjXaFbRgvMgXPopRBKcGUR71aOiD7oOnUq43b5mULEYJAyRenDGftH0rvQ4U28rpeamq7@CgSNN2bcAxwrMEMz6pT46SViw5MaIGrKcf@5fNlnF2QW1Nifn0wRndQ8dmyUEIXPSYgdmfS3gBOV7Gs4Txm7tlumpOo4UjoCZ8gkBH9I8xnQJyebgT0X0EX5BO3BLoVKgaSlwMFo5GyG8yRvkgtXMwJbsT73n2Krc7meX5Lk9xNuorhFeUdCneu7NeIbjhtTIeWlgPXWGAGw0Tg/n1X7aU8eGLquK5TNnl8UqGQZXqBw) - PCRE (no bug)

But `^a\Bb?a\Bb?$` correctly doesn't match `aba`:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3NCsIwEITP9imGtbR6KNhrfxA8FDzrTaukJthCaDVBBI3PXtNY6R4W5tuZ2YrpuleCcUSKIwyhsiw8jxP2J3bcVGu3/P6PvWfdSIFtscsxRiGNOSBqQb4klCnvvJnVL/gapTHiUnepzuPUsZ9nCJD/lskqiT@EHDR3dDGYnceIqxI3RM1dWK0IQQB3HP7s1UMkAMGYCRZMaktpmU7MFnm8a0XPKvYF) - GNU ERE / [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kKbE4Y8HOotTEFAXdohQFdXWFIhsb9XgoUF9aWpKma7EmLjHGKckeTKhAhG7ug6nhKs_IzElV8HQLtlWAmqOQU1MTraCbp6CkkqOkEGudks_FCeRXKagUK8TW1KQmZ-RbF9saWoPFIGpAGpRUqnOsDKwMa5UUbBWUlMGiGiDFYDU1qelFqQUKupmFqUB-kZKCmpoCWBJkT0hRaaqVgoKSQk0NQtAtMacYKKqkaY0QAxrElZKflwrxxYLFiUmJECYA)

21 bytes without word-boundary assertions (GNU ERE or better):

```
^(tut-(tut?|))+tut$\2
```

21 bytes without word-boundary assertions or backreferences (ECMAScript or better):

```
^(?=t)((t?ut)?-tut)*$
```

### Regex (ECMAScript or better), 22 bytes

```
^((?=tut-tut).{1,7})*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU/RTsIwFH3vV5TM0HsXNiAxmtBUnvQD1DejSTMKVku3dJ1OCN8@B3Ew2Hy46T2955x77of8knnidOajPNML5dap/VQ/lRNWfdNHtbovM4CNuBuH1RvAXPjCR3VhvJ2ObncYXlXheIOxT5@803YFGOdGJwpuRtE1Il@mDrSYcDDCKbkw2ipAHAhbGMO1mOKWUKqXoDGr5R6Q19jQ4ZCal8nrQLCA7UFW@Nw7MPFa@uQdHM7ZsyvUjFI2Yw/S5HXLDtqGiXxXBXRPIuQvc/O2@3PUQ@wXdKWn/x6T3sF/hiSgh4sIKUlDJ21heXQg5dHz3PxiTzvLxf5T/k66zoXtmL8) - ECMAScript
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU/fa4MwEH7PX3HU0CTDzvowBqapFLo97qmPY6EbFoTMdlHBIdm/7s5tWlvdQ7jcfT/uu1NizV3z/gnUSqjN8W1vgAYSW7XabnabtSOHo@U0VUu5WkusoaghPeBE1CebZgXMnrOZdEANKMjL17xAuvYXoR@K5KMFIR7Ml4gIiIBqSQCNgKNwPu8ZBhmhyBLmsW4BbynqCwJqAxGznS2TCIBF7HFvcvwyIR16/ZKpkeC0fnjaat28cB6roiwW@MRtHfr3TtzQpvGgNSHkD@rq8H/ZTRCnBWPpeT5hMgn8Z0g8@LmYkIp0dDIUVr0DqXrPS/OrPcMsV/vP@UfpRhcOY34D) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X1qcquDr7@ftGmmt4Brm6KMQGF2cWKmgkWsVYKofq1CnoGKblpmXWZwBZAZG6yvY2ysohRSVplopKCgpKCoqKLkl5hQDeUqaOirxCmn5RQo5mXmpxdax1lxQjf/jNDTsbUtKS3SBWFOv2lDHvFZTS@X/f6gQF5RGZqPysCjErgFTK0IciyFYJXAZWMEFU8QFUQ7VhKy3Am4IVwXcWFTz0aziwu4yhBJMpyG8huFwDM8j@wAA) - Raku<sup>`:P5`</sup>
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDfT8IwEMff@1ecpXGtGT/2ZEJt9iIaE4Nm@ibazKW4xW4sXUlICH873lAEAR@6Xa/f@9z3rs7r9VVc5zUwBwpon0IPamc@tDO1TTPDg37vItY6T63X2aysC2vchE@EnCT9JgghwDPFpP4wraDypvIN1/rm7n6ktQghEoik/TmVpKgK3RjPaZ0503tPs0/v8KNtURaehkC7ERWSTGeOs0INJLNqitiGPz1f342FFEsoppzZl8Y7ayqMRDd6VYpOKipQ3Mzf8QXT4SDsRkJu1IUwWT5rJRKQGkkCmAe@Y5yfI3LweqaCToAtWKk2GyhTn@WcuRAlElrI92Zs2nhtnEOX4kw9JqNbPX7QoyR5SGI6avNDoEPOypg@u7kZAt7oTWobDHE8WKGBDY0yS@XqYLdcyPUb57Hyc9/FI3rLKLxciQu2XnegBRLy87T978d/byeEpwuOS3f5E5CTD/8BSQc20xOyIFs52S9c/BLI4pf5F37QZ9/LQf@d/yN3RxPu2/wC) - PCRE
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFbb5swFIDf@RWnZGrsrHXTp0lFrNqk9WmdpmVvu0gOmODUGIYPLVPEb8@OE5LmwpCQz/U7t6V8ltfL9Gmti6qsEZakC12KSQSHlga1GbTVaqFa76maudEJJEY6B49SW1j1JocS6XkudQoFOdgMa20XIOuF@/GLA@Z1@eLgU5uoCnVJiQHAgzYKstiql43IQpGUqRLkD3n0sckyVav0m5KpqmG@CTs2sl1mr2acR31dd4XRS@75jLl4TiPI9LO2inF@EdvGGK4z5oT600jjWHgzmUxCzlfHoVsCYzgIWBEB9wQC3BBhTnFPkXsbj3/asX8x6ra27qtEVLWFOu4lmraofAHHI9rGLJHW0qTaVg1CDH643sZmfx2qQmjL6TwWQcfTCPr5NvEil@6LapHagxVQZ/oinvI@rSR/RWtBY5kHxLe@HlXc7spQsS3EEqEfnRjAjDDKLjBn/P0ULi/BiCSX9QdkU1rCeDTmmzP671FiklPzBbFqUWw1Zohz2kPGCpFpmzIO9xB@rxt1BxDCHYQPtEhS6PbdWZZHdV0X@EOtfzN2H2OD1/Rzsbq9etfxyZu1P8F6BB4ZBL179x7Kx9pA4HDCeeqrfQAy6PgfMBjBZvogaINdeHCY2O4JQbtnHsNP6hz2clL/tf@z7s4mPGzzHw) - Java
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVLbjpswEH33V0xJtbFTki5dqZUg7Ep96AdU@9BVNkWsYy4qMZYxIpsov15qm5CQSy0BczlzzswYKsQ0pbQd5ZwW9YrB/K0sK/VZspRtZpkQj4hmsYRILJYQwk/ne9P8eXuoX97ffz1nX5sMt78xfgpVrab6IbOd537bk8nHllwiHRcmIozEJy9AJ7lcq0kWrx9RzhUIqd8Rk7KUmJa8UmDVJ2tWVXHKyK5SK9@nGgDzORyixrRxxldFAJKpWnLwgr2lXMc5xwR2CPQRC61WMI4FmXrL8D6AWmMevkQKSuOZglQbFmw5NT7nqU6IWgXQ9WRX5Pt2R1pOkwV9rFrHimbQZLHqSJJSAja0W8NvKVOmipwz3M2Sc7dj1yTb0Os7NSdPAG8J6JzZAh6/8jEJzrK2cHG/hLs76O0P4Xg0JkeYHdusNcHDvqOKxZJmHYNrG3b1LASewHmWNfMBHPDB@REXlXacgXDSyFyxrnJGI70hTA4zzKp8y4znuWbW0kxl6/b2fbgavd99OwIjg9Dhz@m/Q/vcuwG8XXBdeorfILmZ@B8hGoHdCEIb1MPRsHBzZECbI@c5@YXOsJcL/VP/V91dTThs8y9Nijit2mlhrzyyN/4P) - Boost
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/BSsQwEIbv8xRjKjSRbmnxIESCN5/AW12h2CwbiGlJstBd8dlro3bb3cZDmEzy/9/80x39vjX3g/roWuvRHV1mJVgUaAkhwxulT8If/GY8LP8ss4cvdnc7jF9VyTfl9hFPooBda1GjMsGeO98owwFR7fDEsbPKeMp@ey0N1Qxr06CuRrsQ6atJOWqhqyLwIrJieyPSJJ1I0jSCvNiD5IgkiK3Mnazt@57aDEeX1E4iea7HwpGEwbNRsxC4HBIMBIC/zaa6vF92EWHcsLbO7xFI9OM/ICT4sxZAD5Mclsb@TID@zLyEX81ZZrmaP@dfpVttuIz5DQ) - Python
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU9da4MwFH3PrzjG0Y8xg@5lUAlS6Pa4h9G3zkrHsi6QicRILWP76y7a2trqHsLNvefjnquLt32lwfEitqLMWCp2WMyXc6bF5j2E5H6I3adUAopvhckJID8gnXqeFSYPIdKGF4Q1oFZeEHNOX1MaWoVa@Yx593HDOkgdxcRXZvYRRiNL92OHj92xxYBMy9RAgf9CIwJd6kLMAIoZ6NNG5bahrdORe2iT5PF5kSTVejKJuCmMZ9@UfQd3Dz/T25uqclFbEXKE2tr9X3YDxGFBX3qeD5gMAv8ZEhfN1YSUpKWTrrA8OZDy5HlpfrWnm@Vq/zl/L13vwm7MPw) - Ruby
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU9BasMwELzrFYstkBTi0JwKNqaBQm@99VZaMMm6FlUlIyvYxOjtrhKaxIndg9hd7czsTG1atE2FSg3U5u8Wv7D7SFONLd@w4ZPzp9ztXRKeWPXr5aMXCzqwzTJ6Nj@1VLiLREYP@UNWGovFtuJUgdRApa4DpZclpwfRt1Y6TCrTOB/A60yWEIBJoXeJNu7YKvmNLF4wMQZD2AYnSmqEiPITy65eC7etsAksIaBnb3aPKTAPqBoM80sRasq8gMhn81pU@SGGI5GQv3TnOu5vpxngPGFKvf7PiMwu/hMkMZzyEdKRM5yMid1FgXQXzVvxuztjL3f3r/4n7iYJxzZ/AQ) - .NET

```
^                 # Anchor to start of string
(
    (?=tut-tut)   # Assert that the following 7 characters match "tut-tut",
                  # without consuming them.
    .{1,7}        # Skip anywhere from 1 to 7 characters
)*                # Iterate the above as many times as possible
$                 # Assert we've reached end of string
```

Alternative 22 bytes:

```
^(t(?=ut-tut).{0,6})*$
```

### Regex (Python / Ruby), 21 bytes

```
^((?=tut-tut).{,7})*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/BSsQwEIbv8xRjKjSRbmnxIESCN5/AW12h2CwbiGlJstBd8dlro3bb3cZDmEzy/9/80x39vjX3g/roWuvRHV1mJVgUaAkhwxulT8If/GY8LP/MHr7Y3e0w/lQl35TbRzyJAnatRY3KBHfufKMMB0S1wxPHzirjKfvttTRUM6xNg7oa7UKkryblqIWuisCLyIrtjUiTdCJJ0wjyYg@SI5IgtjJ3srbve2ozHF1SO4nkuR4LRxIGz0bNQuBySDAQAP4Wm@ryftlFhHHD2jq/RyDRj/@AkODPWgA9THJYGvszAfoz8xJ@NWeZ5Wr@nH@VbrXhMuY3) - Python
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU9da4MwFH3PrzjG0Y8xg91LoRKk0O1xD6NvnZWOZl0gE4mRWsb21120tbXVPYSbe8/HPVfn74dSg@NV7ESRskTssZgv50yLzTaA5H6A/adUAorvhMkIID8gnWqe5iYLIJKaNwkqQK28ScQ5fUtoYBVq5TPmPUY16yh1FBNfqTmEGAws3Y8cPnSHFgNSLRMDBf4LjRB0qXMxAyhmoM8bldmGNk4n7rGN46eXRRyX69Eo5CY3nn1j9v0w/Rnf35Wli8qJkBPS1Pb/uush9gu60su8x6QX@M@QuKiPJqQgDZ20hcXZgRRnz2vzmz3tLDf7L/k76ToXtmP@AQ) - Ruby

Python and Ruby support the quantifier shorthand of `{,N}` to mean `{0,N}`.

Alternative 21 bytes:

```
^(t(?=ut-tut).{,6})*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/BaoQwEIbv8xTTWDBZXFEKPaSEvfUJerNbkJplA2mUJIK7pc9uTRdXd7WnyWT@/5t/mpM/1uapV19NbT26k0usBIsCLSGk/6Ce7kTrt771LP1Onn/Y5rEfJkXOt/n@Bc8ig0NtUaMywZ06XynDAVEd8Myxscp4yi69loZqhqWpUBeDXYj43cQctdBFFngrsmz/IOIoHknSVIK82VZyRBLEVqZOlvbzSG2Cg0tqJ5G8lkPhSMLiyahZCJz3EQYCgL8cNtb5@7ZbEa4bltbpfwWyOvgPCBH@nQXQwSiHubG7EqC7Mm/hd3vmWe72T/kX6RYXzmP@Ag) - Python
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU/JTsMwFLz7KyYO6oKIlXLooZYVVSocOaDeSoiKcIslE0WOo6ZC8OshC2nTJpzsebO8eSZ7OxYGAs9yL/OExfKA1XK9ZEZu3zmU8DkOH0pLaLGXNiWA2kE51TzJbMoh41o34xWhN94sFIK@xJSXDr3xGfPuw1rVWB3N5GdijwFGo1Luh44Yu@OSAxKjYgsN8QODAHRtMrkAKBagj1udloC2SX/aBkbRw9MqiorXiZ0EIrOezeyUfd3Nv6e3N0XhokoixDZM@3b/l2hAOGzoW8/zgZBB4r9A4qI@mpCctHLSNeanBJKfMi/Dr/Z0u1ztP/fvtetd2K35Cw) - Ruby

## Regex ([Raku](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes)), <s>25</s> 21 bytes<sup><sup>[SBCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)</sup></sup>

```
^tut»((t?ut)?\-tut)+$
```

Ported from a previous (21 byte) version of the "POSIX ERE / RE2 or better" regex.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X1qcquDr7@ftGmmt4Brm6KMQGF2cWKmgoR@rUKegYpuWmZdZnAFkBkbrK9jbKyiFFJWmWikoKCkoKioouSXmFAN5Spo6KvEKaflFCjmZeanF1rHWXFCN/@NKSksO7dbQKLEvLdG0j9EFcjW1Vf7/B9IgNheURmaj8rAoxK4BUytCHIshWCVwGVjBBVPEBVEO1YSstwJuCFcF3Fgk81FsQrOUC7sbEUowHYnwJIYXMIIB2S8A)

Porting the 21 byte lookahead-using version comes to **28 bytes**:

```
^<?before t>((t?ut)?\-tut)*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X1qcquDr7@ftGmmt4Brm6KMQGF2cWKmgoR@rUKegYpuWmZdZnAFkBkbrK9jbKyiFFJWmWikoKCkoKioouSXmFAN5Spo6KvEKaflFCjmZeanF1rHWXFCN/@Ns7JNSgTKpCiV2Ghol9qUlmvYxuiVASkvl/38gDWJzQWlkNioPi0LsGjC1IsSxGIJVApeBFVwwRVwQ5VBNyHor4IZwVcCNRTIfxSY0S7mwuxGhBNORCE9ieAEjGJD9AgA)

### \$\large\textit{Anonymous functions}\$

## [Raku](https://docs.raku.org/), <s>29</s> 25 bytes<sup><sup>[SBCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)</sup></sup>

```
{/^tut»((t?ut)?\-tut)+$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1uplmb7v1o/rqS05NBuDY0S@9ISTfsYXSBXU1tFv/Z/cWKlgoa9nlqagr29glJIUWmqlYKCkoKiooKSW2JOMZCnpKmjEq@Qll@kkJOZl1ps/R@oF6SfC0ojs1F5WBRi14CpFSGOxRCsErgMrOCCKeKCKIdqQtZbATeEqwJuLJL5KDahWcqF3Y0IJZiORHgSwwsYwYDsFwA)

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <sub><sup><s>29</s> <s>28</s></sup></sub> 30 bytes

```
->s{s=~/^\b((t?\But)?-tut)+$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBfT4MwEH@/T3GUZZsxMObjmpPEBz@Bb4DGxaIklRBaIsPoV8fCxmCjvrS9u9@f@7Ws9oc2pda7V9@KfjfP8X691mH8UOmb0NPmvF1sftqGAo5fH5kUKOldaAWIWYqN0/WLSiuOIn/j2NCWdwMZeduEiMU544Yho8D3vbvkhFq8UJ7Jo4QjffFZ6EOIy6WhBYlDK3dlZohFmeUa00gmGCJ7KiuxQ2S4Q/b4KpUpWK8HA1L2ZetiBwUwy3cBhnv6vqwsQDthTh37FhHr4D9BcLFPBVDDAIcj8USfqtRnOajPBhOnC88re7BvO0Lm645xZ2FmHzJN9Qc)

## JavaScript, <s>35</s> <s>34</s> 33 bytes

```
s=>/^\b((t?\But)?-tut)+$/.test(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBRb4MgFIXf@RVMlwLpartXDTXpw5K9721uiVNMWAg6uG4mTX@7w26tttIXuMD5zr2Hz/w7t4WRDax0XYq@4r3l2/V79kEppNmuBZauwK3L@3UEwgK1rE8s3yRGfLXSCEqMyEsltSAsKlwN4lmDMFVeCLqXumkhbkxdCGsjC6XUBxbVmpIj8aD4do8wtnixwBNV3UL0YyQ490wTlmDLHxOnU4NOvW7e7jgJyU2oooqlwYtpRYxxEAdPubKuDNjg4SUUSw6sD/HAIOTyDplP@7S@PHmEfmCOjvceE@/DLUMU4mNAhDp0kqM/8B@funRnO9SdG0w6XfS8ao/8046S@bhj3FmY2YdMU/0C)

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```
$args-match'^\b((t?\But)?-tut)+$'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBBboMwEEX3c4qRGRVQZSndJooiddETdNe0Eo2GYsmB1DgCBXF2atMSSCEb2@P574@/T0XFpsxY647SbdNRYr5KeUzsIQs/9p9RZHf757ONd9K69ZHCrt3QZbvapIXh5JBFpFHlSCo/uX4DiCqN6BI3lVGWZVaUtnX6p76BTi35G4VAWRgk/bZ67@tAxOjZFlmX3B8RRweUeZFzpVXOKCjyRg@UOt5R4as58xoxHNjwJXH72l3EwlvCPSfS0HYBeh7ApfMJh316vq0WhMvAHB3vF0wWG/cMIcA@JUANgxx@wT986lJf7aC@DphMupn5bzwsv3aUzJ87xp2FmX3INNUP)

## Java, 36 bytes

```
s->s.matches("((?=tut-tut).{1,7})*")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBPb4IwFL/3Uzwx0dZoo6clMjTbwdO2i7stO3RYpK4UQotijJ/dVUBFYQdSXn9/Xzdsy0ab1e9JREmcGtjYmWZGSBpkyjciVnTgQgMcuMiXTGt4Z0LBAQEk2Y8UPmjDjD22sVhBZDG8NKlQ669vYOlak4IKsKi8n0t0@BrHkjM1gwC8kx7NNI2Y8UOusYPx3DOZGdmP0MNk@HQkA4ecXOuz9JlSPAWhksyAB4rvLnd4udeGR1QoYtsrA8Ibu7ALheSACz4Nmf7gucHElgIRYNHxxqSSxRZPbDMjFT4beBO36F3WBWnDShNlHd6E4gUrACyp5GptQkxmY@j1QFI/ZOmLwWPS8frdPilsrNFDDg4oSxK5x5LAHJzPNONTAAem4CyY1HZwbEJDJYmLjsfjqQtnBULVQ13O@v/91EJsFzSlt/sWk1bgP0PUhWI5hHJ0oaNSWMnrLvnVDuXXgFrSXeZDPGpve6M0697WbSzTeJD6Vn8)

```
s->s.matches("tut\\b((t?ut)?-tut)+")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBLU8IwEL7nVyxlBhKUDF6phdEDJ/WCN/EQSkqDIe00Wx7j8NsxlFeh9ZTs7vfaXYiV6C5mP3u1TJMMYeFqnqPSPMpNiCoxvONDZdjxSaiFtfAulIFfApDmU61CsCjQPatEzWDpZnSMmTLzr28Q2dyyAgowOmk/H6ePr0mipTADiCDY2@7A8qXAMJaWepjjZDKlFIc5smHXlezBY3vf6YxDYYzMQJk0RwjAyPW5R8dbi3LJlWEuvUFQQc@Hday0BFrgeSzsh9wgZS4UqIiqRtBjJ1ri5qlLhtrQg0Dw5Be5j3FBO7OjiHEKb8rIAhUB1VxLM8eYskEPWi3QPIxF9oK0xxpBu9lmhYwTuvOhERdpqrdUMxiC95nlsg/gQR@8kdDWFZ5zqLA088lut9s34cAgxF3ncKHzW/7fVjXAekKVeu3XiNQO/hMkTSiWI2RDznByJJ7oZZXNRY5sLgYlpxvPO3tSn/YKqca9rltZpnKQ8lZ/)

```
s->s.matches("\\b((t?\\But)?-tut)+")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBLU8IwEL7nV6xlBhKUDF6phZEDJ/WCN@shlJQGQ9pptjzG4bdjKG9aL0k2@71252IpOvPpz04tsjRHmLuaF6g0jwsToUoNb/tQabZ9EmlhLbwLZeCXAGTFRKsILAp01zJVU1i4Hh1jrszs6xtEPrOshAKMjtovh@7TME21FKYPMQQ72@lbvhAYJdJSLwwnlOIgDIcFskEH3fnosZ3vdMaRMEbmoExWIARg5Or0R8cbi3LBlWEuvUFQQdeHVaK0BFrieSLsh1wjZS4UqJiqh6DLjrTU9TOXDLWhe4Hg2S9zH@KCdmYHEeMU3pSRJSoGqrmWZoYJZf0uNJugeZSI/BVplz0ErUaLlTJO6M6Hxlxkmd5QzWAA3mdeyB6ABz3wRkJbV3jOocLSzCfb7XbXgD2DELed/YZO9/X7tqoB1hOq1Mt/jUht4z9B0oByOELW5AQnB@KRfq2yPsuR9dngyunG886e1Ke9QKpxL@NWhqks5HqqPw)

## [Julia](https://julialang.org/) v1.2+, <s>39</s> <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```
s->endswith(s,r"^\b((t?\But)?-tut)+")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVFdSsNAEMbXOcWYYLuLBuybNKQBHzyBb1YhpbvtyrCVZIMhV_AIghShh9LTOGmaJjXpy-7Ozvcz3-7n7jUnk2y_dbTLnQ7ufq6yYKbsMns3bi2ym9R7mS-EcPH8PncyDhyv1548gL_KSCeUqRD1JkVCYzFVyZKMVZmQgLiizSIhLEOjeXlLjXVkhQzZIcQycmmuGMVNUnbFhiRntzgaIT1Nni-jsT_mLuKeJzR3MUbvkUlTRA-n6D1U7rxXXqwJDZYkcFlPuf29-PCxYgHw-FWEZu-eT6sB4DChT23vB0QGG-cEwcd9QIACGjjUxAO9q1Ic5aA4GnScTjz_2cPwtC2kP24btxem9yDdVPWn_AE)

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 40 bytes

```
\(L)grepl('^((?=tut-tut).{1,7})*$',L,,1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVHPSsMwGMdrniKusuSTTNaTslC8eepR8DKE2iUzULKSpFA69gQ-gpcp-Aq-iz6Nqe3WztZDSL4vvz_fL3l9M_t3GX0UTs5uvuiSxrA2Is8oeaT0NnKFm_kFV9uQXe_g8oKwmLEQWvynjeYcV5FUmaAT61ZKT4AjuTE0xkpjW-S5EdY-JEYrvbbUiGQVKy0srQBgizBWklpIE0fJUhPgNgp509Xpc-JlAE-nXufJOl-w0HufRyQggGuOkiKzgkoPY-TeFGKBMWHkLvHdBSYAtVYNjIHvUJptPLgC3ky__z57CXDNQqjNedj759NqBDhOGFK7_ojI6MV_gijAvxERKtEBjhpiS--rlEc5VB4Nek4nnn_s0fi0HWQ4bhd3EGbwIP1Uzaf8AA)

```
\(L)grepl('^tut\\b((t?ut)?-tut)+$',L,,1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVFLTsMwEBXbOYVpUO0RrkR3qFHUHasskdhESGlqF0uRG9mOFAVxAo7ApiBxBe4Cp8EhbZM2YWXPzPvMs9_eze5DRp-lk7Pbb5awGDdGFDmjj650SbJizC1Lh8uZL_H6ivKY8znu8V82uglJHUmVCzaxbq30BEOQW8NiojSxZVEYYe1DarTSG8uMSNex0sKyGhGfgRAlmcUsdYwmmmJoo3nYdnX2lHoZJNOp11lZ5ws-996XEQ0okoajpMitYNLDOL03pVgQQjm9S313QShio9UAYwxfIMu3Hlxj2G6_-7l4DUjDAvDhmoCHs38_rUaA44QhteuPiIwO_hOEgPxFBKjgAIeWuKf3VaqjHFRHg57TieeZPYxv20GG63ZxB2EGD9JP1X7KLw)

```
\(L)grepl('^\\b((t?\\But)?-tut)+$',L,,1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVHPSsMwGMdrniKusuTDDOxNFsrAg6ceBS9B6LZkBkpWkhRKxSfwEbxMwVfwXfRpTO22drZeknxffn--X_L6ZnfvKvkovZpdf1FBU9hYWeSUPAixpNQvhLgpPSxmPqyXF4SljMWwx3-65IrjOlE6l3Ti_FqbCXCktpamWBvsyqKw0rn7zBptNo5ama1TbaSjNQA8IYy1og5WmadEGALcJTFvu2b1mAUZwNNp0Fk6HwoWB-_zhEQEcMPRSuZOUhVgjNzZUs4xJozcZqE7xwSg0WqAKfBntMq3AVwDb6fffZ-9RLhhIRTCNQEPe_98Wo0AxwlDatcfERm9-E8QRfg3IkIVOsBRS9zT-yrVUQ5VR4Oe04nnH3s0Pm0HGY7bxR2EGTxIP1X7KT8)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 47 bytes

```
fn($s)=>preg_match('/^\b((t?\But)?-tut)+$/',$s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBbb4IwGH3vr6i1kTbTCK90Hckyt@xFF@bbcEQNiEmnpNSEZPG3s686BQd76eX0fOfSPMur@yDPckxTWaU7RgsuH3KdbOKvpVlnzBl/RivGTBA9HgwPRgbWOzp2hkCsRLrXjG6lK6iS6SYxBXufP71OueDfeJsyqj4Ko1UCsoqPvIWUJNoRDuTisIIXgIfucORxcWJvebLO9pYiMKh6AmHAMas1BgOQdBc96fQdsLB0fAqrloWJE60hD@/Jt3DyEk9n8SQMZ2FAJhb3MfEZtZl4QOb6kPgYEPK8VAUcCRfHsxyhiohj1ceWgxD0tZ0ve/N8e@sgdg@0R2u8Q6Tz4T9B1MenQgiV6EJH58Hf8aZKeZVD5dWg4XTj@ccedaetKe24dd1WmdaHNFv9AA)

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/), <s>54</s> 53 bytes

```
lambda s:re.match(r'\b((t?\But)?-tut)+$',s);import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBLbsMgEN1ziqldCVCbyFF2WChSFz1Bd3EWpMYKEsYWEMnJ5V3TxLFT0w3DDO8zj/biT43Z9qpuG@vBXVwOV57lUPGi16I@lgIcs3JdC/99IhYXR0L8rvg4e7pb@eF8e8XvjuZ3ASv7qrGgQZkgtna@VIYhAFXBlUFrlfGE3notDdEUhClB71ebA@e4MJiB5nqfsWEQgWWHF45TPCpJU/Lky54lA0gCuApQqZ2E5FMMhUES3Ca0piHgpk8h0BAaIoQYY53fn7sIME5YUqd5RCT68J8gSuE3FkIdGuHoRrzT5yrdQw51D4OZ05PnH3sU33aCLNed4i7CLD5knuoH)

### \$\large\textit{Full programs}\$

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
^\b((t?\But)?-tut)+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8D8uJklDo8Q@xqm0RNNetwRIaqv8/w@kQWwuKI3MRuVhUYhdA6ZWhDgWQ7BK4DKwggumiAuiHKoJWW8F3BCuCrixSOaj2IRmKRd2NyKUYDoS4UkML2AEA7JfAA)

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>25</s> <s>24</s> 21 bytes

```
+`(t?\But|\b)-tut`~=a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fO0GjxD7GqbSkJiZJU7ektCShzjbx////urr/gRyQAJSCkAgWAA)

Thanks to DLosc for demonstrating this syntax. This is apparently shorthand for [`^((t?\But|\b)-tut)+$`](https://tio.run/##dVBLboMwEN37FFOoZFttIqLsjKxKXfQE2YUsSDGKJWOQbSQS5e4UNyGQ4q7GM/M@89yc3anW215WTW0c2LNN4cKTFEqe9SqvjkUOlhmxrnL3fSIGE@I@ss/WXbMjXbnW0bdX/G5pehcwoi9rAwqk9mJr6wqpGQKQJVwYNEZqR@itV0ITRSHXBaj9anPgHGcaM1Bc7RM2DAKw5PDCcYxHJaELHu1MKxhA5MGlhwplBURf@VAYRN5tQivqA276GDwNoSGCjzHW@fu5CwDDhCV1mgdEgov/BFEMv7EQ6tAIRzfinT5X6R5yqHsYzJyePP/Yo/C1E2R57hR3EWbxIfNUPw). This regex is slightly less inefficient speed-wise, but by moving all distinctive operations inside the loop, it allows this shortcut to be used.

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-n`, <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```
p~/^\b((t?\But)?-tut)+$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6BOPy4mSUOjxD7GqbRE0163BEhqq@j//w9kgDhQCkIiWP/yC0oy8/OK/@vmAQA)

Prints `nil` for false and `0` for true, which are respectively falsey and truthy in Ruby. If printing `0` or `1` is desired, replace `p~` with `p !!` (+2 bytes).

## [Perl](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, <s>27</s> <s>26</s> 25 bytes

```
$_=/^\b((t?\But)?-tut)+$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVC9boMwEN79FCdzIqCGBoYssShShz5BR1TktKZBIsbCRqKJ8uqlDm0CCXTx3dnf31mJulx3jRawfgyjkMH@C/NYN9sjZrGqFOtsXb2lW88zSfrcGD8JjD0fcNUxzE4MtOFGAB4YHlxX1YU0NJXUTnHE4H1X7RWzmjzGjBW5Vwr5aXbIwXXBumhTe8iX4TLypVg4C//YK3iYB0/2wU/oa92IDQDd0BdeattS/9RjADmDRn6IHDDrHDgDCbHZzvkuddzfTjPAecKUOtzPiMw@/CdIHOi3IqQlFzj5Jf7RxyrtVY60V4OR043nnT2ZTztApnGHdSfLTD5kvNV3pUxRSd0F6gc)

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 25 bytes

```
'^\<((t?\But)?-tut)+$'XXn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/Xz0uxkZDo8Q@xqm0RNNetwRIaquoR0Tk/bdXDykqTVWvVXdLzClOVf@vDpQDyUMpCIlgqQMA)

MATL appears to have `\<` and `\>` as its word boundary assertions, and apparently doesn't support `\b`, yet somehow still supports `\B`. I can't currently explain this; I thought it used PCRE.

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```
[[ $1 =~ '^\<((t?\But)?-tut)+$' ]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVBLCsIwEN3PKd4i0AQR7N4S8Bpt3UhDdwU7QlD06jHFtklNxE0yyZt5n7mPvTNSSVfXECWqF4pzc5SSdXO6sdJ79udOFGhbp4jMcAV3I0OSByZwueN6@8o05gfS0fCfIckCvwjVgwADMZn3VXfpBxxQQWh6xqksLWT0oZ3JYw27ipFd5SMfG0df5iifJbSkYcIykqjJuv5mLufM7g0)

Zsh uses GNU ERE as its regex engine, so while `\b` would work, `\<` should be slightly more efficient due to only checking for the type of word boundary that can occur at that location.

## [PHP](https://php.net/) `-F`, <s>48</s> <s>47</s> 46 bytes

```
<?=preg_match('/^\b((t?\But)?-tut)+$/',$argn);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62oCg1PT43sSQ5Q0NdPy4mSUOjxD7GqbRE0163BEhqq@ir66gkFqXnaVr//w8UAYlyQWlkNioPi0LsGjC1IsSxGIJVApeBFVwwRVwQ5VBNyHor4IZwVcCNRTIfxSY0S7mwuxGhBNORCE9ieAEjGJD98i@/oCQzP6/4v64bAA) - bare-bones test harness
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBNb4JAFDx3f8WIhNW0BL26IEkPpj21SXtTShBWIaFA1jU1Cr/dLn5ipRx22XlvZt68ebCK96@TDweCBxFMEYFSCNum/umje9t1CsGX/ncgw7hHra/ZvNeT7ux5LfuuKdX5qFv0SQ/EMuuz/ZlIeBjnMDNotrtzx7rQaFVD2izTGMUYYR5xps5C5CHeX96xg5UX0iriwponWX3DDGFxGcKMsIpzIf284Jkvg6XzlsGcnDQq8hMnKUczCNKynB7s9VSDx6KcPKj3FvoWXlnWk7CtM2RIFpiiU1eOnTAMBei7dDQYDSt0HNAuVQKQMc9wCFU3jg19p4aeDr2K3RqbaxxLA69CgLIE3ySS1aIBHAdDeIZxWc6nWPMRoB1HOkCTIF0pTGNYJAwXWJmSKM/4vouaRIhafb3@8938v321NLYT7qlXvEWktfCfIOniEIyQDTm3kyPxRG@qbC5yZHMxaDjdeP6xJ@3TXlvux73GvQtzt5Bmql8) - fancier test harness

Comment: wow, i just wrote a different 22 byter myself

Comment: @thejonymyster Was it the alternative I just edited in?

Comment: no actually :o perhaps ill just share it here for completeness since all pure regexes are bound to be similar :-) `^(?=tu)(t?(ut)?-tut)+$` in js regex, correct me if its wrong though. [regexr link](https://regexr.com/6thur)

Comment: @thejonymyster Oh wow! That is very different. Amazing that it turned out to be exactly the same length.

Comment: It was also wrong :-) false positives on `tut-tutt-tut` EDIT: easily fixed though, misplaced paren on my part

Comment: "True" regex `^tut-tut((t?ut)?-tut)*$` is only one byte longer than the first one.

Comment: @Bubbler that's actually basically where i was before i golfed off a single byte :-) (i just misplaced that one paren `t?(ut)?` instead of `(t?ut)?`)

Comment: -1 byte for the posix one if you replace `tut-tut` with `(?=tu)`, unless im misunderstanding something

Comment: @thejonymyster POSIX ERE doesn't support `(?=..)`.

Comment: @Bubbler weird, i inserted it myself in one of the tio links and it seemed to work :0 but yea fair enough :-)

Comment: @thejonymyster Only the [first TIO link](https://tio.run/##dU/BToQwFDz7vmJSyAImJO4VlnDbZM96M6tBaWSTZtECWaL127Gty5YV7KHtmzcz781L0VSD5EWJWJYIAsjNJng@n2B4CvOs7aIwbPOujfK41fetP4wEOlUHwbHb3mc4m0Ao9Yj4COYLhn1a1nSj60/4DfZK8deqTptsnVrsl2MEzP8SyV2y/mbIwDyLhoZsOYq/Sf6O@PDBdS0ZVivYppnzIDueAAxKOXBbiEajLEodpo2orI988GA0RDqNSTS@0/91tUBcFsylDl8wWWz8Z0gebCqinkY6TYX9xYH6i@e1@Z85010cPl/GhZmtOos73fkH "Bash – Try It Online") is relevant to whether it works in POSIX ERE...

Comment: @tsh Nope, `tutut-tut` is truthy by that, but there's another one for the list of test cases :-)

Comment: raku has the worst lookahead/behind syntax.

Comment: @JoKing Yep, but worse than that, Raku apparently doesn't support backreferences at all. You have to manually "publish" a capture group's value into a standard variable using an embedded code block – but this can't work like a backreference, as the variable's value won't be properly reverted when backtracking. The only way I've found to get proper backreferences is just to use the `:P5` adverb.

Comment: Anything wrong with this golf? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPy4mSUOjxL60RNNetwRIaqv8/w@kQWwuKI3MRuVhUYhdA6ZWhDgWQ7BK4DKwggumiAuiHKoJWW8F3BCuCrixSOaj2IRmKRd2NyKUYDoS4UkML2AEA7JfAA "Retina 0.8.2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Neil Yep, it matches `ut-tut`, etc.; I guess those will have to be more suggested test cases.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the Zsh answers are full programs, not anonymous functions. On TIO you've (or probably GammaFunction, since it looks like you used their test harness) wrapped them into a function called `f` to make it easier to test, but to be technically valid within the rules it's a full program executed like this: https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/OlpBxVDBtk5BPa6ktCQmSUOjxL60RNNeF8jT1FZRV4iN/f//P5ADEoCQAA

Comment: Also, why no Retina full program answer ;-)

Comment: @Deadcode Are you sure about backreferences? Raku uses `$` as the prefix and is zero indexed, e.g. `/(.)$0/`

Comment: @JoKing What I meant is that there are severe limits upon where backreferences can be addressed from, so for example there's apparently absolutely no way to use a nested backreference or even to emulate one. For example I tried to translate [this regex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251603/sum-of-partition-numbers/251650#251650) to native Raku and it's apparently impossible.

Comment: PHP 8.0+ alternative: `fn($s)=>preg_match('/^(tut-\b(tu\Bt?)?)+$/',$s);`. It's longer, but is an anonymous function.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I intentionally omitted it to try to keep the length of my post under control. I've observed that when given a choice between program and function (and also version of the language), people generally post only the one that is shortest. But if you think I should include the function versions of everything anyway, let me know and I might change my mind.

Comment: @Deadcode In this case, I think it is a good idea to include the PHP anonymous function. I know that it is 2 bytes longer, but, you can run it without banging your head in the "try it out" website or without having PHP installed in your system. Also, it's a lot easier to write test cases for it too.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel But... that's the whole purpose of my "fancier test harness". It makes testing the full-program version just as easy as testing a function. I'm guessing you preferred to test it on an PHP online-testing web page instead of the test harnesses supplied here?

Comment: Nice use of `\B` to fix my golf attempt! I'm glad I was at least able to provide inspiration for a byte off.

Comment: @Deadcode I have a strong aversion to the "try it online" service. But, I'm not trying to impose that at all. Just think that the anonymous version is a lot easier for anyone to pick and test it themselves, without using your test code. That's all. I see nothing wrong with it, but, sometimes, playing with the code myself, on my own way, can get me to help others reduce the code size. It's just a little more convenient. And no, I'm not trying to change your mind. I just wanted to post it there in case anyone wanted to use it, or in case you decided to include it in your answer.

Comment: `~/.../` doesn't actually work in ruby, because that is equivalent to `$_=~/.../`, which hapepns to be set becauses of the `gets`.

Comment: @naffetS Thanks. Damn, I used that a few times before, starting in 2021; will have to fix those as well.

Answer (score 14):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <s>66</s> 54 bytes

***-6 bytes** thanks to Neil, **-6 bytes** by switching to `-e` thanks to pxeger.*

```sh
s=xxxxxx$1
repeat $#1 [[ ${s:$[i++]:13} = *tut-tut* ]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY/LCsMgEEX38xUX6iIPApXuAqEfErIoRUlXKdGCNOTbjS15mGipMDjOOHfueavWyiRNlNAohFWV@R7GqRdPcdNgJ466BhtUyepHnjclv4yokOmXLlxkaBqbEsmuhxZKI6G5s9x@vn9FPsYHwtGtHhGJNn4JpgMBEuxj3mXi3nY4O0B2pdGnMrSIkS9rVn0y68b96oML3@nB3UYXeA/4/0LwGcJO)

<s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY/PCsMgDMbveYrAPNiWwWS3QtmDiIcxlPbUUR3I2j67c1v/2OqYIIkm@fL9nrp2imbU6cp@DmHfCJ28y6tBcmDIOZJel4Q3RSFKdh6xwtw8zNHfHIUYBmkb4zIA1XZopDZIYarPMcy3r0RjeiAeXf8TIsnCL8GsB0SF5G3eZ/JWt3jymOQCY0hlYRaDUNYu@mCXjdvVOxeh0527lS7yHvH/hWAThHsB)</s>

The problem stated is equivalent to: Every sliding 13-character window of `xxxxxx[string]xxxxxx` contains `tut-tut`. In Bash and Zsh, the `${var:${idx}:13}` is valid even if the string isn't long enough, so the trailing `xxxxxx` are unneeded.

We loop over each window, and `exit` out if any single test fails thanks to `errexit`.

Comment: You can use `bye` instead of `exit` for -1 byte

Comment: In fact, if you use Zsh `-e`, you can remove `||exit` completely

Comment: The six trailing `x`s seem unnecessary.

Answer (score 10):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 21 bytes

```apl
∧/7∨/'tut-tut'⍷6∘↓⍣¯1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhEcdy/XNH3Ws0FcvKS3RBWL1R73bzR51zHjUNvlR7@JD6w3/Vz/qmwpUmQahHvVufdTd8qij/VHvvFog/g/VxwWlkdmoPCwKsWvA1IoQx2IIVglcBlZwwRRxISuvgOvjqoCbhGokmunILkCzFeFqDDdh@AvZcQA)

```apl
               6∘↓⍣¯1   pad with leading spaces
     'tut-tut'⍷         find occurrences of tut-tut
∧/7∨/                   present in every group of 7 consecutive positions
```

Answer (score 8):

## Python3, 61 bytes:

```
f=lambda x:x==''or'tut-tut'==x[:6|f(x[4:])|f(x[6:])|f(x[7:])]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBNCsIwEIXXzilCN0nEiqhUKeQKXqB2UbHBQE1KjBDBu8ei/W8KLkJefubN96Z8mZuSu2OpneOsyO6Xa4ZsbBnDWGlsniasFmbMJnH05sQm@zilXxE14lCJ1HGlkUBCIi4Kk2tyUjJfoSAIag@o974enjwf/QXT0u7eY@J9mDGseNePshCG4LPElMawKLWQhnAiKIWfxiFebjcUYDazBQtNM/i1rZv3GWwLA7bFG3KOkPuxRlG6UUyCTob1f2L3AQ)

Comment: 70: `f=lambda x:x==''or'tut-tut'==x[:7]and any(f(x[i:])for i in range(1,8))`

Comment: I think you can replace `and ` with `*` though it's slow

Comment: And you only need to check displacements 4, 6, and 7: [61 bytes](https://tio.run/##jZBNCsIwEIXXzilCN0nEiqhUKeQKXqB2UbHBQE1KjBDBu8ei/W8KLkJefubN96Z8mZuSu2OpneOsyO6Xa4ZsbBnDWGlsniasFmbMJnH05sQm@zilXxE14lCJ1HGlkUBCIi4Kk2tyUjJfoSAIag@o974enjwf/QXT0u7eY@J9mDGseNePshCG4LPElMawKLWQhnAiKIWfxiFebjcUYDazBQtNM/i1rZv3GWwLA7bFG3KOkPuxRlG6UUyCTob1f2L3AQ "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: @xnor Thank you, updated

Answer (score 8):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 70 bytes

```
b-->"tut-tut".
n-->(b;"ut-tut";"-tut"),(n;"").
t-->b;b,n.
+X:-t(X,[]).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBLDoMgFNxzCsIKIngASXoKFybWGGnRNkGxiqm3t2isX1yQx/vNm5m60UoXrP2@h4DBVpq0nipprrICP3UnlEw/nTaypfDxypqW@GAQjN2Q6QyzD/mgsikWHM0FjqZAKK44Qnbe2L7gglY@8KKAGRzROCH@MOS6yZTCpSyFbHBIYQwWWLp8D@mp4N643HRirC032lXvCjkhFAIvtOLBhcg/yBgX0BX9cKff3hz//ZbLnteR5JnynLml7madcne@uSxx@Xu25@7B0aEf)

-4 from jo king.

Comment: Prolog also supports regex, which can be used to match against the string for [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/XzvCSrcoNT43sSQ5Q0MpTqOktEQ3JiYJSMfEOJXYa9praqso6URo6v3/n5ZflJiTo5GbmpuUWqQRoqMQzaUEUg7ESjpwJhoXQwC7Dpw6sZqBkMJuGi45XCbHauoocGmHaOpxceHwJMwQEA03FGE6mj0VyHaC2BXIbkF1F7ojMZ0M5WH3KoparN5FCTdsQYItfDGDJ0ZbARRCAA)

Comment: I think `phrase` is superfluous, it can just be `t(X,[])`

Comment: @JoKing yeah, the regex one i wasn't interested in. It'll just make deadcode's answer longer. I didn't know that phrase wasn't needed. will change that.

Answer (score 8):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 50 bytes

```python
def f(s):s[:7]=="tut-tut"and f(s[~ord(s[7])%5|4:])
```

Signals by exit code: errors out if the input is "tut-tut"-decomposible.

### How?

Recursively checks that input starts with "tut-tut". Based on the next character directly computes where the next "tut-tut" has to start.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6   7   8 9 ...
               ---
t u t - t u t | - |
              |   |
 ==>    t u t | - | t u t
               ---


               ---
t u t - t u t | u |
              |   |
 ==>        t | u | t - t u t
               ---


               ---
t u t - t u t | t |
              |   |
 ==>          | t | u t - t u t
               ---
```

The figure shows offsets inferred from char at position 7:

- `"-"` -->  4
- `"u"` -->  6
- `"t"` -->  7

The magic formula `~x%5|4` implements this map. `x` is the code point of input character.

Importantly, any input is mapped to 4,5,6,7, so the algorithm can neither get stuck nor skip any characters.

Now, if we can cover the input with `"tut-tut"`s we will eventually reach the end and error out as soon as we try to access out-of-bounds characters. Otherwise the algorithm will simply stop at the first place that cannot be covered.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3jVJS0xTSNIo1rYqjrcxjbW2VSkpLdIFYKTEvBSQRXZdflAKkzGM1VU1rTKxiNaE6HdPyixRyFDLzFPILUvM0DDStuBRKiiqt0jRy9IpLijILNDQ1rQuKMvNKNJT8lDS5FFIrklMLSqygQpFKUIMW3GLMh9rJBaWR2ag8LAqxa8DUihDHYghWCVwGVnDBFHFBlEM1IeutgBvCVQE3FtV8NKu4sLsMoQTTaQivYTgcw_PIPoAEPAA)

#### Thanks to eagle-eyed @Jonathan Allan for spotting a problem with my first attempt.

#### Wrong [Python](https://www.python.org), 54 bytes

```python
def f(s):s[:7]=="tut-tut"and f(s[~ord(s[7])%31%12%8:])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3zVJS0xTSNIo1rYqjrcxjbW2VSkpLdIFYKTEvBSQRXZdflAKkzGM1VY0NVQ2NVC2sYjWhuh3T8osUchQy8xTyC1LzNAw0rbgUSooqrdI0cvSKS4oyCzQ0Na0LijLzSjSU_JQ0uRRSK5JTC0qsoEKRSlCDFtxizIfaywWlkdmoPCwKsWvA1IoQx2IIVglcBlZwwRRxQZRDNSHrrYAbwlUBNxbVfDSruLC7DKEE02kIr2E4HMPzyD6ABDwA)

Comment: @JonathanAllan I guess you are right. Back to the drawing board...

Comment: Are there actually any inputs that result in an infinite loop? It appears that `tut-tutc` returns a false positive but does at least halt.

Comment: @Deadcode looks like a maximum recursion depth error to me.

Comment: Ah, indeed. I forgot that the recursion error would be silenced in your ATO link due to the try/except being indiscriminate about which types of exceptions it intercepts.

Comment: The problem with your first attempt being that it could get stuck if the formula evaluated to `0`?

Comment: @Neil exactly,  for example tut-tutc.

Answer (score 7):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>16</s> <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
mp13l‛≠₈‹∞vcg
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#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) | [12 bytes with `g` flag](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#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)

Returns `1` for true, or falsy for false (`0` or an empty list).

```
mp13l‛≠₈‹∞vcg
m              # Mirror the input - append its reverse
 p             # Append the input to that
  13l          # Get all overlapping strings of length 13
     ‛≠₈‹∞vc   # For each, does it contain "tut-tut"?
            g  # Minimum. Returns an empty list for an empty list (no idea why)
```

-3 from porting Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer!

-1 thanks to emanresu A.

Previously:

### [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 16 bytes

```
6Iø.13l`≠₈-`∞vcA
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiNknDuC4xM2xg4omg4oKILWDiiJ52Y0EiLCIiLCJ0dXQtdHV0XG50dXQtdHV0LXR1dFxudHV0LXR1dHV0LXR1dFxudHV0LXR1dHR1dC10dXRcbnR1dC10dXQtdHV0LXR1dC10dXRcbnR1dC10dXR1dC10dXQtdHV0dXQtdHV0XG50dXQtdHV0dXQtdHV0LXR1dHR1dC10dXRcbnR1dC10dXQtdHV0dXQtdHV0dHV0LXR1dFxudHV0LXR1dHR1dC10dXR1dC10dXQtdHV0dXQtdHV0XG54XG50dXRcbnR1dC1cbi10dXRcbnR1dC10dXR4XG50dXQtdHV0dFxueHR1dC10dXRcbnR0dXQtdHV0XG50dXQtdHUtdHV0XG50dXQtdHV0dHV0XG50dXQtdHV0LXR1dHRcbnR1dC10dXR0dXQtdHVcbnR1dC10dXR1dHV0LXR1dFxudHV0LXR1dHR1dHR1dC10dXRcbnR1dC10dXR1dHV0LXR1dHV0LXR1dCJd)

Uses the same idea as @GammaFunction's Zsh answer.

```
6Iø.13l`≠₈-`∞vcA
6Iø.              # Surround the input with 6 spaces on both sides
    13l           # Get all overlapping strings of length 13
       `≠₈-`∞vcA  # Do all of them contain "tut-tut"?
```

Comment: [13](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#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)

Comment: Ah nice, forgot about that useless overload.

Comment: BTW, the question specifies "You can use any two distinct, consistent values to distinguish the true and false cases," which doesn't allow turning falsey inputs into 0 sometimes and empty list other times.

Answer (score 5):

## [Curry (PAKCS)](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/), 42 bytes

```
f""=1
f(a@(_:_++b)++c)|a=="tut-tut"=f$b++c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4tKqrULUjMTi7@/z9NScnWkCtNI9FBI94qXls7SVNbO1mzJtHWVqmktEQXiJVs01SSgIL/cxMz8xRsFdIUYDJQCkIiWEr/AQ)

Returns `1` for truth, and nothing otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 42 bytes

```raku
{^.comb⊆m:ex/tut\-tut/>>.&{.from..^.to}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1uplmb7vzpOLzk/N@lRV1uuVWqFfklpSYwukNC3s9NTq9ZLK8rP1dOL0yvJr639X5xYqaASr2Brp6CnlqaQll@kkJOZl1r8H6gcpIULSiOzUXlYFGLXgKkVIY7FEKwSuAys4IIp4kJWXgHXx1UBNwnVSDTTkV2AZivC1RhuwvAXsuMA)

An anonymous function that takes a string and returns a true/false value for if it is composed of overlapping 'tut-tut's.

#### Explanation

```raku
{                                      } # Anonymous function block
 ^.comb    # The range 0 to length of input
       ⊆   # is a subset or equal to
        m:ex/tut\-tut/                  # Match all instances of 'tut-tut'
                      >>.&{           } # And map them to
                           
                           .from..^.to  # The range of covered indexes
```

This basically finds the indexes covered by each 'tut-tut' and makes sure that they cover the entire string. Note that you could easily generalise this function to any string.

Comment: Porting [Bubbler's regex approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251772/tut-tut-tut-tut-tut/251780#comment560670_251777) comes to [29 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1uplmb7v1o/rqS0JEYXSGholNiXlmjagzmaWir6tf@LEysVVOIVbO0U7PXU0hTS8osUcjLzUout/wOVgJRxQWlkNioPi0LsGjC1IsSxGIJVApeBFVwwRVzIyivg@rgq4CahGolmOrIL0GxFuBrDTRj@QnYcAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 39 bytes

```
:a
s/tut-tut/TUTTUT/i
ta
s/[^TU]//
T
cN
```

[Truthy test cases -- outputs nothing](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ODVlebSSbl6RUuyCpaUlaboWN9WtErmK9UtKS3SBWD8kNASI9DO5SkCi0XEhobH6-lwhXMl-EOVQXQturoXq4ILSyGxUHhaF2DVgakWIYzEEqwQOAyGuBgA)

[Falsy test cases -- outputs one N for each line](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ODVlebSSbl6RUuyCpaUlaboWN9WtErmK9UtKS3SBWD8kNASI9DO5SkCi0XEhobH6-lwhXMl-EOVQXQtunq7gAqoHYV0uXTALQpbqwoSBuALGKOGqgLK4SuCMUiSWLqpGKBNVAdQkGANNPZCC8dAMLsE0qRROg0iInwA)

The idea here is quite simple:

- Continuously replace `tut-tut` with `TUTTUT`, using case-insensitive matching, until the input stops changing.
- Check if there are any lowercase characters or `-` left.
- If so, output an `N` for failure.  Otherwise, output nothing for success.

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 29 bytes, straight regex, thanks to Deadcode

```
s/^((t?\But)?\b-tut)+$//
t
cN
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ODVlebSSbl6RUuyCpaUlaboWe4v14zQ0SuxjnEpLNO1jknRLgLS2ir4-VwlXsh9EDVTpgluMlUBZkAouKI3MRuVhUYhdA6ZWhDgWQ7BK4DKwggumiAuiHKoJWW8F3BCuCrixSOaj2IRmKRd2NyKUYDoS4UkML2AEA7JfIFEAAA)

Thanks to Deadcode for this alternate approach which forgoes looping and solves it with a single application of a true regex.

Comment: This is creative, but I feel obligated to point out that the same effect can be achieved with the same flags in [33 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ODVlebSSbl6RUuyCpaUlaboWNxWL9eM0NErsY5xKSzTtY5J0S4C0toq-PldJIleyH5dVIkQhVP2CW4yVQBUgVVxQGpmNysOiELsGTK0IcSyGYJXAZWAFF0wRF0Q5VBOy3gq4IVwVcGORzEexCc1SLuxuRCjBdCTCkxhewAgGZL9AogAA "sed - Attempt This Online")

Comment: Very much appreciated!  I will have to update it a bit later today as I am in the middle of work stuff.

Comment: Why would the `/i` version loop infinitely? Surely it would stop when it runs out of `-`s. Also, I can't get the ATO link to work, it outputs `N` for any input.

Comment: @Neil re: ATO, it is working for me (on original and now-updated code).  I separated truthy/falsy links to make the expectations clearer.  Lmk if that works for you.  Re: looping, you are correct!  The looping problem was happening on earlier version, and I forgot to recheck when I updated to remove the `-`.  Code and explanation are now updated.  Thanks!

Comment: I see now, the truthy cases output nothing at all, so when you had a mix of truthy and falsy cases, you couldn't tell which ones were truthy. Very confusing.

Comment: Fair enough... original combined one was admittedly a bit lazy.

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 20 bytes

```
Ẹ|a₀"tut-tut"sl;?b₍↰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GuHTWJj5oalEpKS3SBWKk4x9o@6VFT76O2Df//w0QhJAjDlAEA)

#### Explanation

This is a pretty straight-at-the-problem approach; possibly something more subtle would be shorter.

```
Ẹ|a₀"tut-tut"sl;?b₍↰
Ẹ                     Either the input is the empty string
 |                    Or
  a₀                  A prefix of the input
    "tut-tut"         is "tut-tut"
             s        Take a nonempty substring of "tut-tut"
              l       Get its length
               ;?b₍   Remove that many characters from the start of the input string
                   ↰  Recurse
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>24</s> 23 bytes

*Edit: saved 1 byte based on Dominic van Essen's comment.*

```
±Λ≤7Ẋ-J¥¨μζ-μζ¨X7¹e_6→L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9DGc7MfdS4xf7irS9fr0NJDK87tObdNF0QcWhFhfmhnarzZo7ZJPv///y8pLdEFYgiJYAEA)

### Explanation

```
±Λ≤7Ẋ-J¥¨μζ-μζ¨X7¹e_6→L

±Λ≤7                          check if all differences are ≤7
    Ẋ-                        take the difference of all adjacent elements in list
      J                       put indices list the into the middle of [-6,1+len(input)]
       ¥                      create indices list of all occurrences of "tut-tut" in substring list
        ¨μζ-μζ¨               "tut-tut"
                X7¹           create list of substrings of input with length 7
                   e_6→L      list [-6,1+len(input)]
```

Comment: Nice answer & welcome to code golf!  You can also save a byte by using the compressed string ```¨μζ-μζ¨``` for ```"tut-tut"``` instead of building it with ```hD"tut-"```...

Comment: Thank you! :) I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
žO.øü13"tut-"ûδåP
```

Port of [*@GammaFunction*'s Zsh answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251775/52210), so make sure to upvote him/her as well!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6D5/vcM7Du8xNFYqKS3RVTq8@9yWw0sD/v8H8YAYQoIwlAIA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn3l/6P7/PUO7zi8x9BYqaS0RFfp8O5zWw4vDfiv8x/EBWIuKI3MRuVhUYhdA6ZWhDgWQ7BK4DKwggumiAuiHKoJWW8F3BCuCrixSOaj2IRmKRd2NyKUYDoS4UkML2AEA7JfAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
žO                # Push constant string "aeiouy"
  .ø              # Prepend and append this string to the (implicit) input
    ü13           # Pop and create overlapping parts of size 13
       "tut-"û    # Push string "tut-" and palindromize it to "tut-tut"
              δ   # Map over each overlapping part using "tut-tut" as argument:
               å  #  Check if the part contains "tut-tut" as substring
                P # Product to check if all are truthy
                  # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 58 bytes

A non-regex solution.

```javascript
f=([c,...a],i)=>i>6?!c:c=="tut-"[i&3]&&f(a,-~i)|3%~-i&f(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVKxDoIwEN39C0mENqFdSBxMiptf4FYZmgpaQ6iBYjAx/HpVFjRpyw0deu/u3t27dxMP0clW3Q1p9Lm0tmKIy5RSKopUYZarfLtfy51kLDK9IRFXcVbEcYVESkaFX9lmJOr7xVbqptN1SWt9QQk/tr25PosEr37jFZrafF6EfUgYXcJB7aE0EMI5E0QNTA2M8VeRnBp@EHXnUnpwt/eQOsK@Eb2jh3caAus6oCEgUlC/BW0XhXeDoOuGGkMOHrIZwDIAs8JMTTyOmKC52r4B)

#### How?

We use a pointer \$i\$ into the string \$s=\$ `"tut-tut"`. At each iteration, we make sure that the current character from the input string matches \$s[i]\$, then we either increment \$i\$ or restart with \$i=0\$ if we are allowed to do so. The parsing is successful if we end up with \$i=7\$ exactly when the end of the input string is reached.

The table below summarizes after which positions it's possible to restart with \$i=0\$ and how this can be computed with the expression `3 % ~-i & 1`.

| i = position | character | restart after? | 3 % ~-i | 3 % ~-i & 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | t | No | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | u | No | NaN | 0 |
| 2 | t | No | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | - | Yes | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | t | No | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | u | Yes | 3 | 1 |
| 6 | t | Yes | 3 | 1 |

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
m0;w13Ƥ“"ṁĿ4ṘṘ»Ṃ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of characters and yields `1` if constructible or `0` if not.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/XwLrc0PjYkkcNc5Qe7mw8st/k4c4ZQHRo98OdTf8f7t5ydM/h9kdNa1S8gUTk//8lpSW6QMwFpZHZqDwsCrFrwNSKEMdiCFYJXAZWcMEUcUGUQzUh662AG8JVATcWyXwUm9As5cLuRoQSTEciPInhBYxgQPYLAA)**

#### How?

The input must (a) start with `tut-tut`, (b) end with `tut-tut`, and (c) have `tut-tut` as a contiguous substring of all of its length \$13\$ slices. We can, however, just test that (c) holds for the input concatenated with its reverse concatenated with the input (e.g. `abc` -> `abccbaabc`). This works since `tut-tut` is palindromic and any bad starts or bad ends in the input will now nest between any `tut-tut`s.

```
m0;w13Ƥ“"ṁĿ4ṘṘ»Ṃ - Link: list of characters, S e.g. "abc"
m0               - reflect -> "abccba"
  ;              - concatenate -> "abccbaabc"
      Ƥ          - for infixes...
    13           - ...of length 13:
   w   “"ṁĿ4ṘṘ»  -   first 1-indexed index of "tut-tut" or 0 if not found
               Ṃ - minimum (an empty list yields 0)
```

---

Bit of a shame it takes half the code to make "tut-tut"!

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>22</s> <s>18</s> 17 bytes

*Edit: saved <s>4</s> 5 bytes based on [Jonathan Allan's idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251810/95126)*

```
▼M€X13‼S+↔⁰¨μζ-μζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9G0Pb6PmtZEGBo/atgTrP2obcqjxg2HVpzbc26bLoj4//9/SWmJLhBDSAQLAA)

```
      ‼   ⁰             # apply twice to the input:
       S+↔              #   join to itself reversed
   X13                  # and split this into strings of 13 characters;
 M                      # now map over these
  €                     #   do they contain
           ¨μζ-μζ¨      #   the compressed string "tut-tut"?
▼                       # and return the minimum result
```

Comment: @Calga - I couldn't get that to work, because the implicit ```⁰``` gets added at the end, instead of directly after the ```D+¹↔```, and if I re-arrange using ```m``` and putting ```D+¹↔``` last, I need to include the closing ```¨``` after the compressed string.  Or am I missing a trick...?

Comment: No, you are right, my bad. Deleted my comment, but apparently too late.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 39 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.replace(/(?=tu)((t?ut)?-tut)*/,"")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZLLCsMgEEX3@QxXTmmabTfWH8lGQqQpQcSMwX69SUmhxCfdOHDmcuflS6xiGcyksV3vXjLv2MPdzKhnMYy0o5yhBUqRWwTe4v5euish4LWZFFKCxuLz3SsCTXMguUOLHykBiFiO5zMVs7pp2f6nqRSqigpFv1rSKynmJVyXC90i9xOI6yc6yjXpkp2foEvOmB@8sI8QV1b8X@II6ZsWr1T8DcHp/AY)

Returns a falsy string if the string is correctly composed of `tut-tut`s, and a truthy string otherwise.

Mostly the same logic as my (slightly broken) [regex solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251772/tut-tut-tut-tut-tut#comment560666_251777), except instead of having the "this regex matches the entire string or else it fails" logic be in the regex, its in the fact that we only delete one occurrence of the pattern. If the entire string is not composed of the pattern, there will be string remaining after the replacement, and in js, any nonempty string is truthy, with the empty string being the only falsy string :-)

(in case you wonder why this doesn't fail for cases where two valid strings are concatenated: regex is greedy, and will grab the largest match it can grab)

Breakdown:

```javascript
x=>x.replace(/(?=tu)((t?ut)?-tut)*/,"") // full function

x=>x.replace(/                    /,"") // return the string with exactly one
                                        // match of the following regex removed
              (?=tu)                    //   string starting with "tu"
                    (           )*      //   which contains at least 0 of
                                        //   the following pattern
                                        //   (actually at least 1, since otherwise,
                                        //   the pattern would be empty and 
                                        //   thus would fail the "tu" check)
                     (t?ut)?-tut        //     any of "-tut"
                                        //     (will never be at the start due to the
                                        //     "tu" check, but can appear in cases
                                        //     where the entire "tut" overlaps),
                                        //     "ut-tut"
                                        //     (in cases where just the "t" is overlapping,
                                        //     also can never be at the start)
                                        //     or "tut-tut"
                                        //     (this one always comes first
                                        //     due to the "tu" check)
```

BTW this regex saves a byte over the straightforward regex `/tut-tut((t?ut)?-tut)*/` because we don't actually have to use the entire "tut-tut"; the first group `((t?ut)?-tut)` is forced to complete to `tut-tut` once it's forced to start with `tu`, if that makes sense... :-)

Comment: -4 bytes if i get off my lazy ass and switch from `x.replace(/`...`/,"")` to `/`...`/.test(x)` but im tired of generating tio links and changing code breakdowns etc

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 36 bytes

```factor
[ R/ tut\b((t?ut)?-tut)+/ matches? ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVC5DsIwDN39FR5bIegOQ0fEwkDFBAwhMsfQkqSuGoT49lAEvUgYotjxO/xyEpJvxm2z1Xo5R11jSbqiQlKJyhDzXZlrwWjoTFbhAkDXD@CKp81p72E97gLAMMGn9u8BkeDgnyBYaFHwwX9ZQ7LtVMB2ugODkdWPK4SX7CH@ln1KL4P3D6MwT3A73CTY1PtjFHFacZy@J/EkwVywvFCZ4sHlQuHMvQA)

Port of Deadcode's (Bubbler's/thejonymyster's) [regex answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251777/97916).

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 63 bytes

```factor
[ "xxxxxx"dup surround 13 clump [ "tut-tut"swap subseq? ] ∀ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVG7DsIwDNz9FVZ3KiE2GBgRCwtiQh1KG0pFm6Z5qEUIiZHv5EdCgD5JiBQlse/OvvgYRrLgerddb1ZzLCsUpFSERkRgwgvFUprgmXBKMsxDefIVTaMiJsg4kfLCeEolLgDK6gpSyYnZ7Tm8j18OoJtgU/u4Q8SZ@CcINbQo@OIb1pBcdypQd7qDAqNSP1XB3WQPsbvsXVoerH8YmbmB3qNXf5YXK4ZCcTM9GuN0hlGmcoYm36A9UYVvxMGMeokBPh93DHRuYr5@AQ)

Port of GammaFunction's [Zsh answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251775/97916).

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
⬤θ№✂⁺×⁶ψθκ⁺¹³κ¹…tut-⁷
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMxJ0ejUEfBOb8UyAnOyUxO1QjIKS3WCMnMTS3WMNNRqNTUUSgE4mwdBbCEoTGQDeQbArFzZXJOqnNGfoGGUklpia6SjoK5JhBY//8P4gIxlIKQCNZ/3bIcAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for a valid string, nothing if not. Explanation: A port of my golf to @GammaFunction's zsh answer.

```
 θ                      Input string
⬤                       All indices satisfy
      ⁶                 Literal integer `6`
     ×                  Repetitions of
       ψ                Null byte
    ⁺                   Plus
        θ               Input string
   ✂          ¹         Sliced from
         κ              Current index to
           ¹³           Literal integer `13`
          ⁺             Plus
             κ          Current index
  №                     Contains
                tut-    Literal string `tut-`
               …        Extended to length
                    ⁷   Literal integer `7`
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 24 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
☼▌☼▐l£{_C<ÿtut-ñ╧\╞};]ε*
```

Port of [*@GammaFunction*'s Zsh answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251775/52210), so make sure to upvote him/her as well!

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7n6OgbqUQW1mY8//RjD2PpvWAyQk5hxZXxzvbHN5fUlqie3jjo6nLYx5NnVdrHXtuq9b//0ogUSBW4oKxUHnofKzKcWnDZgBCBqtROKRwG1sBUQRVCqRgGuEGoJpUgWQoSDuSVSi2orkAwzkQDlY/ICvE5g3kwMDiUSxBhuJnAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
☼▌               # Prepend a leading "100000" in front of the (implicit) input-string
  ☼▐             # Append "100000" as well
l£               # Push the input-string, pop and push its length
  {            } # Loop that many times:
   _             #  Duplicate the current string
    C<           #  Pop the copy, and keep its first 13 characters
      ÿtut-ñ     #  Push string "tut-", and palindromize it to "tut-tut"
            ╧    #  Check if the string contains this "tut-tut" as substring
             \   #  Swap so the string we've duplicated is at the top of the stack again
              ╞  #  Remove its leading character
;                # After the loop, discard the remaining string from the stack
 ]               # Wrap everything else on the stack into a list
  ε*             # Product (reduce by multiplication) to verify whether all checks were
                 # truthy
                 # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 101 bytes

```rust
|s:&str|(0..s.len()).scan(0,|r,i|{if s[i..].starts_with("tut-tut"){*r=7}*r-=1;Some(*r)}).all(|i|i>=0)
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ab36eb7d3a2f58e531a798f15cd87573)

Returns a boolean with the obvious meaning.

Answer (score 2):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), <s>78</s> 68 bytes

```
[range(length) as $i|"xxxxxx\(.)"[$i:13+$i]|contains("tut-tut")]|all
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z@6KDEvPVUjJzUvvSRDUyGxWEEls0apAgxiNPQ0laJVMq0MjbVVMmNrkvPzShIz84o1lEpKS3SBWEkztiYxJ@f/fyifC0ojs1F5WBRi14CpFSGOxRCsErgMrOCCKeJCVl4B18dVATcJ1Ug005FdgGYrwtUYbsLwF7Lj/uUXlGTm5xX/1w0CAA)

<s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z9aTyGxWEGlvEappLREF4iVajLzijNTUjWKEvPSUzWAMjmpeeklGZpgdZk1ShVgEAOU0VSKVsm0MjTWVsmM1YytSczJ@f8fagoXlEZmo/KwKMSuAVMrQhyLIVglcBlYwQVTxIWsvAKuj6sCbhKqkWimI7sAzVaEqzHchOEvZMf9yy8oyczPK/6vGwQA)</s>

Port of my Zsh answer. <s>The `<> as $<>` feels optimizable, but I couldn't figure it out.</s> *EDIT: Turns out, it was optimizable!*

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>94</s></sup> 86 bytes

```c
d;b;f(char*s){for(b=~0;b&&s[3]|b+4;s-=b=d&b|d==1?0:~3)s+=d=strstr(s,"tut-tut")-s;b=b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVLNUoMwEL73KTKdaScpMFKpB43Rg@NTUA5NCMqotMPGkbGljy6G8FOg1IPMJmSz@337kxXOixBFEVJOIyxeN@kCyD7appizo0v5fA6@Fxy4taLgMM7COT@EjC0f3bujR8BiIQOVasFgT9WncvSaEgcoZ5zmRZwo9LGJE0zQfoL0ZyIgJUGBHyCG9i3IRs1xoJ5djCMuIkc5TqZxtku2P5iz2q3xLv8t@kQzIMy65IamG7SfwDCb89xqbbymnu9oXb0GjdU@1sheH3Jqnrl8d5ntpFAyrN55aaNL4v5b6mhim4Ayo6U3Kd5k6gf@qhqvdfZ8vc5un/S6KdPu6F6TrR53hMuU4ySUmYa5tD7eI4i/5TbCTTHkqr5YtDcUWZbxJoasmvPOrGu@at6NU0BbexkRtDXCijB29PoWqS1tC4fQXapdIjydAXIe0CxEM1gnujxlI7DbJgBjMiAVKp/kxY@I3jcvUDhfvw)

*Saved 8 bytes thanks to [c--](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/112488/c)*

Inputs a pointer to a string.
Returns `~3` if the input is constructed of overlapping or concatenated instances of the string `"tut-tut"` or `0` otherwise.

Comment: [86 bytes](https://tio.run/##nVLNUoMwEL73KTKdaScpMFKpB43Rg@NTUA5NCMqotMPGkbGljy6G8FOg1IPMJmSz@337kxXOixBFEVJOIyxeN@kCyD7appizo0v5fA6@Fxy4taLgMM7COT@EjC0f3bujR8BiIQOVasFgT9WncvSaEgcoZ5zmRZwo9LGJE0zQfoL0ZyIgJUGBHyCG9i3IRs1xoJ5djCMuIkc5TqZxtku2P5iz2q3xLv8t@kQzIMy65IamG7SfwDCb89xqbbymnu9oXb0GjdU@1sheH3Jqnrl8d5ntpFAyrN55aaNL4v5b6mhim4Ayo6U3Kd5k6gf@qhqvdfZ8vc5un/S6KdPu6F6TrR53hMuU4ySUmYa5tD7eI4i/5TbCTTHkqr5YtDcUWZbxJoasmvPOrGu@at6NU0BbexkRtDXCijB29PoWqS1tC4fQXapdIjydAXIe0CxEM1gnujxlI7DbJgBjMiAVKp/kxY@I3jcvUDhfvw), returns `~3` or `0`

Comment: @c-- Nice one - thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 16 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
pÔiU ãD eø`t©-t©
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=cNRpVSDjRCBl%2bGB0qS10qQ&input=WwoidHV0LXR1dCIKInR1dC10dXQtdHV0IgoidHV0LXR1dHV0LXR1dCIKInR1dC10dXR0dXQtdHV0IgoidHV0LXR1dC10dXQtdHV0LXR1dCIKInR1dC10dXR1dC10dXQtdHV0dXQtdHV0IgoidHV0LXR1dHV0LXR1dC10dXR0dXQtdHV0IgoidHV0LXR1dC10dXR1dC10dXR0dXQtdHV0IgoidHV0LXR1dHR1dC10dXR1dC10dXQtdHV0dXQtdHV0IgoKIngiCiJ0dXQiCiJ0dXQtIgoiLXR1dCIKInQtdHV0IgoidHUtdHV0IgoidHV0LXR1dHgiCiJ0dXQtdHV0dCIKInh0dXQtdHV0IgoidHR1dC10dXQiCiJ0dXR1dC10dXQiCiJ0dXQtdHUtdHV0IgoidHV0LXR1dHR1dCIKInR1dHR1dC10dXQiCiJ0dXQtdHV0LXR1dHQiCiJ0dXQtdHV0dC10dXQiCiJ0dXQtdHV0dHV0LXR1IgoidHV0LXR1dHV0dXQtdHV0IgoidHV0LXR1dHR1dHR1dC10dXQiCiJ0dXQtdHV0dXR1dC10dXR1dC10dXQiCl0KLW1S)

```
pÔiU ãD eø`t©-t©     :Implicit input of string U
p                    :Append
 Ô                   :  Reverse
  iU                 :Prepend input
     ã               :Substrings of length
      D              :  13
        e            :All
         ø           :  Contain
          `t©-t©     :    Compressed string "tut-tut"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 58 bytes

Assumes non-empty input

```c
f(char*s){s=bcmp(s,"tut-tut",7)?!*s:f(s+4)|f(s+6)|f(s+7);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVJbT4MwFH7frziSkLQbxOnURRF9MP4Kt4fZtRvRwcKpkYj8dbFAua74YNPm9Ny@c2XujrE8F4TtN/EUaYr@KzscCTqW/JCuepazpI9nU7wTBGdX9LsgNxVZUi/Lg1DCYROEhEI6AXVKJJAcJb6swYe0RYL6O2BPBGaPUU8jRqsyo43p/kBOtFltXdDGu4UZACZd8BKmG7SfwDCb09w0Z66pZ2usq9cgU@2mRvb6kHnlmIu58@TImeTbas4XDozd@b@vjsaiEKVeLbbn7I3HerlWyfPlKrl9Uu@6SLrDL@pcRRQDKRIOwi1PlNvc0997wOCLR4LUpdBzLZg2Eg9ms9KalmDVlnc2XeFV214arb1GX0REpRVE0r6UK2nTvKHbMVYmglg2gvsA9hZsXIWqNOkAOk316Pt8rWGzSZb/MPG@2WHufv4C)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 62 bytes

```c
f(char*s){s=bcmp(s,"tut-tut",7)?0:!s[7]|f(s+4)|f(s+6)|f(s+7);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVJbT4MwFH7frzguIWk3iPNKFNEH46/YeMCu3YiOLZwaiZO/LpZSGLDOB5s2p@f2nSvzVoyVpSBsHWcTpHsMX9lmR9Adyw/pqTd2ffo0uz/DuR99C4LTa6rJbU18GhRlkkrYxElKKOxHoI5GA8lR4jyCEPYHNGi@A/ZIYPc46WnFOKjsaKd0fyDnxqyxrmjrfYAZAOZdcA3TDdpPYJjNcW6Gs9fUs7XW1WuQrXZbI3t9KAI95mruPN9xJvmynvOFC6fu7N/XRGPbFKVZLbbm7I1nZrkW@cvlIr97Vu@mSrrDXzW5im0GpEo4SZc8V26zwHwfAJMvvhWkKYWeG8GklQQwnWprqsHqLe9susKrt10bRUGrryKi0goiaV/KlbRt3tBtlykTQcYOgvcIzhIcXKSqNOkCum31GIY8MrDFqCh/mHiPV1h6n78)

-7 bytes from xnor's comment to another answer and 2 from ceilingcat

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 57 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.split`-tut`.every(i=>+{ut:1,tut:1,'':x[3]+1}[j=i])>j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVJBCoMwELz3GV6iWAXpTYjHvqC3VFBsbCPBiIkSKX172nqxhSTuJYfM7szu7HT1XMtmZINKenGjpsVG40KncuBMVYmaVJXSmY5LyHARPyeVZ0e1vgjlmpzKOHuRDrMyKjrTiF4KTlMu7iEil3FSj6VE0eH3vw2DT/@XOIhciB/dw0H0UBmI4FYJkgaWesb460DXnpxrLm1Oazu9Q9Ty7RrRObp/J@1Z1wJpj0le/3a83TXeDoKu6yOGHNwXM0BkAGGFhTpxJGKFtm7zBg)

Regless

See another regless solution [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251796/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-e`, 19 bytes

```
ʷ{;"tut-tut"=ip,}ᵗN
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpJuqlLsgqWlJWm6FttOba-2ViopLdEFYiXbzAKd2odbp_stKU5KLoYqWXCLcTNcBReMhcpD52NVjksbNgMQMliNwiGF29gKiCKoUiAF0wg3ANWkCiRDQdqRrEKxFc0FGM6BcLD6AVkhNm8gBwYWj2IJMhQ_QyIPAA)

A port of [my Curry answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251779/9288). See also [@DLosc's Brachylog answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251821/9288).

```
ʷ{;"tut-tut"=ip,}ᵗN
ʷ{              }       Loop until failure
  ;                         Split the input into two parts
   "tut-tut"=               Check if the second part is "tut-tut"
             ip             Take a proper prefix of the second part
               ,            Append it to the first part
                 ᵗN     Check if the result is empty
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 26 bytes

I know it's not as short as some other answers, but here's my solution.

```
^(tut(-tut))(\1|(ut)?\2)*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qkcD1P06jpLREQxdIaGpqxBjWaAAZ9jFGmloq//8DBUESXFAamY3Kw6IQuwZMrQhxLIZglcBlYAUXTBEXRDlUE7LeCrghXBVwY5HMR7EJzVIu7G5EKMF0JMKTGF7ACAZkvwAA)