# Write "tut-tut-tut" without using "tut"

Tags: code-golf, string, restricted-source

Following this question: [Tut-tut-tut-tut-tut](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251772/tut-tut-tut-tut-tut)

Write a program that writes "tut-tut-tut" **without** using the characters "t", "u" or "-" in the code itself.

This is code golf, shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: In general, "Do X without Y" questions are not very well received due to being overused. I highly suggest you use the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=modifieddesc) next time.

Comment: What makes this challenge, fundamentally, different rom the original? The vast majority of answers there will be able to use trivial workarounds to replace `t`/`u`/`-`, such as using code points.

Comment: see [this meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges/8079#8079) for more information

Comment: Borderline dupe of [around a dozen challenges listed here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string+restricted-source+code-golf).

Comment: Can I use non-ascii t's like superscript `ᵗ`?

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Bî`¡s,`cÄ
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=Qu5goXMsYGPE)

```
Bî`¡s,`cÄ
B             :11
 î            :Repeat to length B
  `¡s,`       :  Compressed string "sts,"
       c      :  Map charcodes
        Ä     :    Add 1
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Windows Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd), <strike>169</strike> 115 bytes

No code points, but assuming capital letters are OK for the output, as this will produce TuT-TuT-TuT

```
@for /f %%a in ('sc^|find "CO"') do @se%OS:~9% q=%%a
@se%OS:~9% a=%q:~8,1%%OS:~9%%q:~6,1%%OS:~9%
@echo %a:~1%%a%%a%
```

Length calculated by using Unix/LF as EOL, without an EOL at the end of the last line.

Shaved of 54 bytes thanks to @jdt, who posted a solution using code points (which I wanted to avoid), but contained three `t`s. Thinking about ways to fix this made me have another go at mine as well.

The first issue with Batch is that you can't even `set` a variable without using a `t`.
But Batch will expand variables in a command first and then take the resulting line verbatim, so the forbidden characters can be picked from a variable. As luck would have it, there is a default environment variable with only two letters, and it even has the T at the last position (allowing to drop the substring length when extracting the T): `OS=Windows_NT`.
So a `T` in a command line can be replaced by `%OS:~9%`, which solves most of the problems; but no such luck for `U` or `-`.

`@for /f %%a in ('sc^|find "CO"') do @se%OS:~9% q=%%a`
This will use the help for sc.exe, find the line            `continue--------Sends a CONTINUE control request to a service.`, break it into tokens at spaces (discarding empty fields), and set the variable `q` to `continue--------Sends`, where `u` and `-` are at single-digit positions.

`@se%OS:~9% a=%q:~8,1%%OS:~9%%q:~6,1%%OS:~9%`
This sets `a` to `-TuT` by picking characters from `OS` and `q`.

`@echo %a:~1%%a%%a%`
This prints `a` three times, with the first instance `%a:~1%` starting with the second character to remove the leading `-`.

---

### Alternative answer by [@jdt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41374/jdt), 118 bytes

```
@for %%a in (84,85,84,45,84,85,84,45,84,85,84) do @(cmd /C exi%OS:~9% %%a&echo|se%OS:~9% /p=%%^=Exi%OS:~9%CodeAscii%%)
```

@jdt posted this in a comment for initially 110 bytes, but it used `exit`, `set`, and `ExitCodeAscii` in the original. Replacing the `t`s with `%OS:~9%` brought it to 128, some more golfing brought it down to a one-liner with 118 bytes.

---

---

### Previous version

```
@for /f %%a in ('help^|find "SE%OS:~9,1% "') do @%%a s=%%a 
@for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic/?^|find "/E"') do @%s%q=%%a
@%s%a=%q:~10,1%%q:~3,1%%q:~1,1%%q:~3,1%
@echo %a:~1%%a%%a%
```

Used the line `SET            Displays, sets, or removes Windows environment variables.` of the `help` output to set a variable to `SET` .
Above is the "safe" version (178 bytes) that should work with localized versions as well.
In the optimized version for **English** versions of cmd.exe **only** (otherwise the first line might run some unexpected commands, and/or not work at all), the first line changes to this, for a total of 169 bytes:
`@for /f %%a in ('help^|find "s e"') do @%%a s=%%a`  <sup>(this line ends with a trailing space!)</sup>

Comment: [110 byte](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/98hNTkjXyE/LY0rLb9IQVU1USEzT0HDwkTHwlQHSJqASQy2pkJKvoIGV3JuioK@s0JqRWYJSCsXyKya4tQSBf0CW1XVOFtXoIRzfkqqY3FyZqaqKpfm//8A) I'm sure this can be golfed futher :-)

Comment: @jdt I spy with my little eye something that looks like a **t** in `exit`, `set`, and `ExitCodeAscii` ;-). Fixed it for 128, then golfed it down to a one-liner with 118 bytes; see above.

Comment: Cool! It reminds me of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/185872/dad-jokes-are-fun/185908#185908) answer from years ago.

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 11 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
11⥊"rsr+"+2
```

`"rsr+"+2` add 2 to the code points of "rsr+" giving "tut-"

`11⥊` cyclically reshape to length 11

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=ZuKGkDEx4qWKInJzcisiKzI=)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2.7 and 3.xx, <s>45</s> 44 bytes

This was harder and easier than I though...

```python
exec('prin\x74(("\x2d\x74\x75\x74"*3)[1:])')
```

I've tested it on Python 2.7.11+, 3.9.6 and 3.10.5.

Good 'ol <del>evil</del> <del>eval</del> exec to the rescue!

---

Thanks to [@Dingus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92901/dingus) for pointing out a mistake, and [@Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler) for saving 1 byte.

---

---

## Alternative answers

Personally, I feel these are against the spirit of the challenge, and that's why they aren't replacing the "main" answer.

### Python 2.7 and 3.xx, 40 bytes

This is an alternative provided by [@Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler).
It uses "TUT" instead of "tut", for the string, saving 1 byte.
I modified a little, to save 3 more bytes.

```python
exec('prinT(("\x2dTUT"*3)[1:])'.lower())
```

This was edited to use `exec` to run in Python 2.7.

### Python 2.7 and 3.xx, 40 bytes

This alternative was written by [@py3programmer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/110681/py3programmer).
It produces the correct output, and avoids the `[1:]` string indexing.

```python
exec("prinT('TUT\x2d'*2+'TUT')".lower())
```

Comment: `-1` isn't allowed (`~0` is an easy fix).

Comment: Or bring `\x2d` to the front and do `[1:]` for -1 byte, and it also seems that `'TUT'.lower()` is 1 byte shorter than `\x74\x75\x74`.

Comment: @Dingus Fixed it, thank you. @Bubbler I found a solution that saves 4 bytes, using `'prinT(("\x2dTUT"*3)[1:])'.lower()` instead of `'TUT'.lower()`. However, I feel this goes against the spirit of the challenge. While (strictly speaking) it doesn't break the rules at all, and must be a valid solution, I just feel like it is a little ... iffy... dirty... skirting in a gray area...

Comment: We could also use `exec("prinT('TUT\x2d'*2+'TUT')".lower())`, as it also has 40 bytes.

Comment: @py3programmer Thank you! Didn't knew that `exec` existed. I replaced all instances of `eval` with `exec` and the code now runs in Python 2.7. I've added it as an alternative answer as well, with credits to you.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell) (Core or Windows), 46 bytes

No code points; taking advantage of the long cmdlet names for a change ...

```powershell
$ofs='';"$((gal oh|% R*e)[3,2,1,2])"*3|% S*g 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyU/rdhWXd1aSUVDIz0xRyE/o0ZVIUgrVTPaWMdIx1DHKFZTScsYKBasla5g@P8/AA)

```powershell
$ofs='';                                       # set the output field separator to an empty string     
            gal oh                             # gal is an alias for Get-Alias; oh is an alias for Out-Host; returns an AliasInfo object
                  |% R*e                       # pipe the AliasInfo object for "oh" to % (an alias for ForEach-Object), and call its member ResolvedCommandName, which will return the string "Out-Host"
           (            )[3,2,1,2]             # take the characters at positions 3, 2, 1, 2 from "Out-Host" (-, t, u, t)
        "$(                       )"           # evaluate that in a subexpression $() and stuff it all into a single string "-tut"
                                    *3         # "multiply" with 3 to get "-tut-tut-tut"
                                      |% S*g 1 # pipe that to ForEach-Object again, and call its member "SubString" to get everything starting at position 1
```

Comment: Your code begins with `-`, which is one of the banned characters.

Comment: OK, that was way too exposed to be noticed. Let's see ...

Comment: Fixed; thanks for noticing, @Dingus

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 51 bytes

```c
i;f(*b){for(i=0;i<4;b[i++]=i^3?762606932:7632244);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///P9M6TUMrSbM6Lb9II9PWwDrTxsQ6KTpTWzvWNjPO2N7czMjMwMzS2MjK3MzYyMjERNO69n9mXolCbmJmnoamQjWXAhCABJJK06ItDGKtwQJpGkCuJoRdUASUTtNQUi1W0lGACNf@/5eclpOYXvxftxwA)

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>69</s> 63 bytes

```c
f(){syscall(1,1,L"\x2d747554\x2d747574\x2d747574\x747574",15);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///P01Ds7q4sjg5MSdHw1DHUMdHKabCKMXcxNzU1ATGMkdhQWglHUNTTeva/7mJmXkamgrVXApAADTMmqv2/7/ktJzE9OL/uuUA)

-6 bytes thanks to ceilingcat!!

Comment: [60 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///XzklNS0zL1WhQsHczMjMwMzSzISrMjrWtrpC19hIpwIEa63TNDSriyuLkxNzcjQMdQx1KnUMTTWta//nJmbmaWgqVHMpAAFQkTVX7f9/yWk5ienF/3XLAQ "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 70 bytes

```
p"#{[116,117,116,45,116,117,116,45,116,117,116].map{|c|c.chr}.join()}"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BJuTra0NBMx9DQXAdEm5jq4ObG6uUmFlTXJNck6yVnFNXqZeVn5mlo1ir9/w8A)

Comment: [60 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BJuTraTMdcx0xH19BUB40Vq5ebWFBdk1yjkaxtaGigqZecUVSrl5WfmaehWav0/z8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

Four different alternatives:

```
…TUTl45ç«11∍
.•x`•45ç«11∍
'±È3£45ç«6∍û
"vwv/"ÇÍç6∍û
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOykNCQHBPTw8sPrTY0fNTRq8Ol96hhUUUCkEARVT@08XCH8aHFEEEzoNjh3TpcSmXlZfpKh9sP9x5eDhX7/x8A)

Without the [restricted-source](/questions/tagged/restricted-source) it would have been just 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) shorter:

```
"tut-"11∍
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fqaS0RFfJ0PBRR@///wA)

**Explanation:**

Part 1 alternatives:

```python
…TUT       # Push string "TUT"
    l      # Convert it to lowercase
     45    # Push 45
       ç   # Convert it to a character with this codepoint: "-"
        «  # Append the two together: "tut-"

.•x`•      # Push compressed string "tut"
     45ç«  # Same as above

'±È       '# Push dictionary string "tutorial"
   3£      # Only keep its first 3 characters: "tut"
     45ç«  # Same as above

"vwv/"     # Push string "vwv/"
      Ç    # Convert it to a list of its codepoint-integers: [118,119,118,47]
       Í   # Decrease each by 2
        ç  # Convert it from codepoint-integers to a list of characters
```

Part 2 alternatives:

```python
11∍        # Extend it to size 11: "tut-tut-tut"
           # (after which the result is output implicitly)

6∍         # Extend it to size 6: "tut-tu"
  û        # Palindromize it: "tut-tut-tut"
           # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to use the dictionary?* and *How to compress strings not part of the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `` .•x`• `` is `"tut"` and `'±È` is `"tutorial"`.